# Check if a class has a member function of a given signature

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I'm asking for a template trick to detect if a class has a specific member function of a given signature.

The problem is similar to the one cited here
http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/071.htm
but not the same: in the item of Sutter's book he answered to the question that a class C MUST PROVIDE  a member function with a particular signature, else the program won't compile. In my problem I need to do something if a class has that function, else do "something else".

A similar problem was faced by boost::serialization but I don't like the solution they adopted: a template function that invokes by default a free function (that you have to define) with a particular signature unless you define a particular member function (in their case "serialize" that takes 2 parameters of a given type) with a particular signature, else a compile error will happens. That is to implement both intrusive and non-intrusive serialization.

I don't like that solution for two reasons:

1. To be non intrusive you must override the global "serialize" function that is in boost::serialization namespace, so you have IN YOUR CLIENT CODE to open namespace boost and namespace serialization!
2. The stack to resolve that
   mess was 10 to 12 function invocations.

I need to define a custom behavior for classes that has not that member function, and my entities are inside different namespaces (and I don't want to override a global function defined in one namespace while I'm in another one)

Can you give me a hint to solve this puzzle?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes What kind of answer are you looking for? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10707822/947836) by Mike Kinghan goes quite in depth and is using C++11 stuff.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882588/correct-signature-of-detect-presence-of-containerreserve) is the modern version you are looking for?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you may exploit SFINAE to detect function presence at compile-time. Example from my code (tests if class has member function size_t used_memory() const).

```
template<typename T>
struct HasUsedMemoryMethod
{
    template<typename U, size_t (U::*)() const> struct SFINAE {};
    template<typename U> static char Test(SFINAE<U, &U::used_memory>*);
    template<typename U> static int Test(...);
    static const bool Has = sizeof(Test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char);
};

template<typename TMap>
void ReportMemUsage(const TMap& m, std::true_type)
{
        // We may call used_memory() on m here.
}
template<typename TMap>
void ReportMemUsage(const TMap&, std::false_type)
{
}
template<typename TMap>
void ReportMemUsage(const TMap& m)
{
    ReportMemUsage(m, 
        std::integral_constant<bool, HasUsedMemoryMethod<TMap>::Has>());
}
```

Comment: The example is missing the definition of 'int_to_type'.  Obviously it doesn't add to the answer, but it does mean that people can see your code in action after a quick cut & paste.

Comment: A simple definition of int_to_type could be: 'template <int N> struct int_to_type {};'. Many implementations keep the paramter N value either in an enum or else in a static integer constant (template <int N> struct int_to_type { enum { value = N }; }; / template <int N> struct int_to_type { static const int value = N; })

Comment: When using C++0x you can simply return the type you want and write "decltype(Test<T>(0))" whenever you need the type.

Comment: Simply take boost::integral_constant instead of int_to_type.

Comment: What does U::* mean *exactly*. Could anyone point to the standard?

Comment: @JohanLundberg It's a pointer-to-(non-static-)member-function. For example, `size_t(std::vector::*p)() = &std::vector::size;`.

Comment: Is it possible to check pass function name as second template parameter, i.e. `HasMethod<Type,method_signature>`?

Comment: This is not working for me because the compiler prefers the Test(...) option, even when the other would work too :/. Ie, it fails the way it is, but when I comment out the Test(...) line, it works (if the method is present). How can I make the Test(...) into a true catch-all AFTER the SFINEA one?

Comment: Oh, I figured out why it fails.. my method is private :/

Comment: In case of protected methods it requires anaccessor template derived from the class of question. In case of private method this will not work

Comment: What if type of `used_memory` can be any not only `size_t`? How to implement it?

Answer (score 168):

Here's a possible implementation relying on C++11 features. It correctly detects the function even if it's inherited (unlike the solution in the accepted answer, as Mike Kinghan observes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707822/947836)).

The function this snippet tests for is called `serialize`:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Primary template with a static assertion
// for a meaningful error message
// if it ever gets instantiated.
// We could leave it undefined if we didn't care.

template<typename, typename T>
struct has_serialize {
    static_assert(
        std::integral_constant<T, false>::value,
        "Second template parameter needs to be of function type.");
};

// specialization that does the checking

template<typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct has_serialize<C, Ret(Args...)> {
private:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T*)
    -> typename
        std::is_same<
            decltype( std::declval<T>().serialize( std::declval<Args>()... ) ),
            Ret    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        >::type;  // attempt to call it and see if the return type is correct

    template<typename>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};
```

Usage:

```
struct X {
     int serialize(const std::string&) { return 42; } 
};

struct Y : X {};

std::cout << has_serialize<Y, int(const std::string&)>::value; // will print 1
```

Comment: Does this work if Y does not have a method called "serialize"? I don't see how it would return a false value if the method "serialize" didn't exist.

Comment: @Collin in that case substitution of template parameter fails for first overload of check and it's discarded from overload set. It falls back to the second one that returns false_type. This is not a compiler error because SFINAE principle.

Comment: Oh, and the arrow is from the new return value syntax in C++11, described here: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html

Comment: @jrok is there a way to add an extra template argument to this struct so you can also pass to it the function name you want to check, (eg. serialize)

Comment: @elios264 There isn't. You can use a macro to write a template for each function you want to check for.

Comment: Any particular reason why the argument for check  is of type T* rather than T or T&?

Comment: I've figured it out. Without a pointer type it's hard to pass the template argument.

Comment: But what if the `serialize` itself accepts a template. Is there a way to test for `serialize` existence without typing the exact type?

Comment: I think that it can be simplified like https://stackoverflow.com/a/60603142/3676427

Answer (score 42):

The accepted answer to this question of compiletime member-function
introspection, although it is justly popular, has a snag which can be observed
in the following program:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

/*  Here we apply the accepted answer's technique to probe for the
    the existence of `E T::operator*() const`
*/
template<typename T, typename E>
struct has_const_reference_op
{
    template<typename U, E (U::*)() const> struct SFINAE {};
    template<typename U> static char Test(SFINAE<U, &U::operator*>*);
    template<typename U> static int Test(...);
    static const bool value = sizeof(Test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char);
};

using namespace std;

/* Here we test the `std::` smart pointer templates, including the
    deprecated `auto_ptr<T>`, to determine in each case whether
    T = (the template instantiated for `int`) provides 
    `int & T::operator*() const` - which all of them in fact do.
*/ 
int main(void)
{
    cout << has_const_reference_op<auto_ptr<int>,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<unique_ptr<int>,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<shared_ptr<int>,int &>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Built with GCC 4.6.3, the program outputs `110` - informing us that 
`T = std::shared_ptr<int>` does *not* provide `int & T::operator*() const`.

If you are not already wise to this gotcha, then a look at of the definition of
`std::shared_ptr<T>` in the header `<memory>` will shed light. In that
implementation, `std::shared_ptr<T>` is derived from a base class
from which it inherits `operator*() const`. So the template instantiation
`SFINAE<U, &U::operator*>` that constitutes "finding" the operator for
`U = std::shared_ptr<T>` will not happen, because `std::shared_ptr<T>` has no
`operator*()` in its own right and template instantiation does not
"do inheritance".

This snag does not affect the well-known SFINAE approach, using "The sizeof() Trick",
for detecting merely whether `T` has some member function `mf` (see e.g.
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/1362568) and comments). But
establishing that `T::mf` exists is often (usually?) not good enough: you may
also need to establish that it has a desired signature. That is where the
illustrated technique scores. The pointerized variant of the desired signature
is inscribed in a parameter of a template type that must be satisfied by
`&T::mf` for the SFINAE probe to succeed. But this template instantiating
technique gives the wrong answer when `T::mf` is inherited.

A safe SFINAE technique for compiletime introspection of `T::mf` must avoid the
use of `&T::mf` within a template argument to instantiate a type upon which SFINAE
function template resolution depends. Instead, SFINAE template function
resolution can depend only upon exactly pertinent type declarations used
as argument types of the overloaded SFINAE probe function.

By way of an answer to the question that abides by this constraint I'll
illustrate for compiletime detection of `E T::operator*() const`, for
arbitrary `T` and `E`. The same pattern will apply *mutatis mutandis*
to probe for any other member method signature.

```
#include <type_traits>

/*! The template `has_const_reference_op<T,E>` exports a
    boolean constant `value that is true iff `T` provides
    `E T::operator*() const`
*/ 
template< typename T, typename E>
struct has_const_reference_op
{
    /* SFINAE operator-has-correct-sig :) */
    template<typename A>
    static std::true_type test(E (A::*)() const) {
        return std::true_type();
    }

    /* SFINAE operator-exists :) */
    template <typename A> 
    static decltype(test(&A::operator*)) 
    test(decltype(&A::operator*),void *) {
        /* Operator exists. What about sig? */
        typedef decltype(test(&A::operator*)) return_type; 
        return return_type();
    }

    /* SFINAE game over :( */
    template<typename A>
    static std::false_type test(...) {
        return std::false_type(); 
    }

    /* This will be either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` */
    typedef decltype(test<T>(0,0)) type;

    static const bool value = type::value; /* Which is it? */
};
```

In this solution, the overloaded SFINAE probe function `test()` is "invoked
recursively". (Of course it isn't actually invoked at all; it merely has
the return types of hypothetical invocations resolved by the compiler.)

We need to probe for at least one and at most two points of information:

- Does `T::operator*()` exist at all? If not, we're done.
- Given that `T::operator*()` exists, is its signature 
  `E T::operator*() const`?

We get the answers by evaluating the return type of a single call
to `test(0,0)`. That's done by:

```
    typedef decltype(test<T>(0,0)) type;
```

This call might be resolved to the `/* SFINAE operator-exists :) */` overload
of `test()`, or it might resolve to the `/* SFINAE game over :( */` overload.
It can't resolve to the `/* SFINAE operator-has-correct-sig :) */` overload,
because that one expects just one argument and we are passing two.

Why are we passing two? Simply to force the resolution to exclude 
`/* SFINAE operator-has-correct-sig :) */`. The second argument has no other signifance.

This call to `test(0,0)` will resolve to `/* SFINAE operator-exists :) */` just
in case the first argument 0 satifies the first parameter type of that overload,
which is `decltype(&A::operator*)`, with `A = T`. 0 will satisfy that type
just in case `T::operator*` exists.

Let's suppose the compiler say's Yes to that. Then it's going with
`/* SFINAE operator-exists :) */` and it needs to determine the return type of
the function call, which in that case is `decltype(test(&A::operator*))` -
the return type of yet another call to `test()`.

This time, we're passing just one argument, `&A::operator*`, which we now
know exists, or we wouldn't be here. A call to `test(&A::operator*)` might
resolve either to `/* SFINAE operator-has-correct-sig :) */` or again to
might resolve to `/* SFINAE game over :( */`. The call will match 
`/* SFINAE operator-has-correct-sig :) */` just in case `&A::operator*` satisfies
the single parameter type of that overload, which is `E (A::*)() const`,
with `A = T`.

The compiler will say Yes here if `T::operator*` has that desired signature,
and then again has to evaluate the return type of the overload. No more
"recursions" now: it is `std::true_type`.

If the compiler does not choose `/* SFINAE operator-exists :) */` for the
call `test(0,0)` or does not choose `/* SFINAE operator-has-correct-sig :) */`
for the call `test(&A::operator*)`, then in either case it goes with
`/* SFINAE game over :( */` and the final return type is `std::false_type`.

Here is a test program that shows the template producing the expected
answers in varied sample of cases (GCC 4.6.3 again).

```
// To test
struct empty{};

// To test 
struct int_ref
{
    int & operator*() const {
        return *_pint;
    }
    int & foo() const {
        return *_pint;
    }
    int * _pint;
};

// To test 
struct sub_int_ref : int_ref{};

// To test 
template<typename E>
struct ee_ref
{
    E & operator*() {
        return *_pe;
    }
    E & foo() const {
        return *_pe;
    }
    E * _pe;
};

// To test 
struct sub_ee_ref : ee_ref<char>{};

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Expect Yes" << endl;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<auto_ptr<int>,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<unique_ptr<int>,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<shared_ptr<int>,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<std::vector<int>::iterator,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<std::vector<int>::const_iterator,
            int const &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<int_ref,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<sub_int_ref,int &>::value  << endl;
    cout << "Expect No" << endl;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<int *,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<unique_ptr<int>,char &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<unique_ptr<int>,int const &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<unique_ptr<int>,int>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<unique_ptr<long>,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<int,int>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<std::vector<int>,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<ee_ref<int>,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<sub_ee_ref,int &>::value;
    cout << has_const_reference_op<empty,int &>::value  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Are there new flaws in this idea? Can it be made more generic without once again
falling foul of the snag it avoids?

Comment: This is neat, and also works with C++03 with gcc/clang __typeof__() in place of decltype().

However, I've found an issue when the method has both const and non-const overloads. In this case neither overload is detected

Answer (score 21):

Here are some usage snippets:
*The guts for all this are farther down

**Check for member `x` in a given class.  Could be var, func, class, union, or enum:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK(x);
bool has_x = has_member_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member function `void x()`:**

```
//Func signature MUST have T as template variable here... simpler this way :\
CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_SIG_CHECK(x, void (T::*)(), void__x);
bool has_func_sig_void__x = has_member_func_void__x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member variable `x`:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK(x);
bool has_var_x = has_member_var_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member class `x`:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK(x);
bool has_class_x = has_member_class_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member union `x`:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK(x);
bool has_union_x = has_member_union_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member enum `x`:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK(x);
bool has_enum_x = has_member_enum_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for any member function `x` regardless of signature:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_CHECK(x);
bool has_any_func_x = has_member_func_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

OR

```
CREATE_MEMBER_CHECKS(x);  //Just stamps out the same macro calls as above.
bool has_any_func_x = has_member_func_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Details and core:**

```
/*
    - Multiple inheritance forces ambiguity of member names.
    - SFINAE is used to make aliases to member names.
    - Expression SFINAE is used in just one generic has_member that can accept
      any alias we pass it.
*/

//Variadic to force ambiguity of class members.  C++11 and up.
template <typename... Args> struct ambiguate : public Args... {};

//Non-variadic version of the line above.
//template <typename A, typename B> struct ambiguate : public A, public B {};

template<typename A, typename = void>
struct got_type : std::false_type {};

template<typename A>
struct got_type<A> : std::true_type {
    typedef A type;
};

template<typename T, T>
struct sig_check : std::true_type {};

template<typename Alias, typename AmbiguitySeed>
struct has_member {
    template<typename C> static char ((&f(decltype(&C::value))))[1];
    template<typename C> static char ((&f(...)))[2];

    //Make sure the member name is consistently spelled the same.
    static_assert(
        (sizeof(f<AmbiguitySeed>(0)) == 1)
        , "Member name specified in AmbiguitySeed is different from member name specified in Alias, or wrong Alias/AmbiguitySeed has been specified."
    );

    static bool const value = sizeof(f<Alias>(0)) == 2;
};
```

***Macros (El Diablo!):***

**CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK:**

```
//Check for any member with given name, whether var, func, class, union, enum.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK(member)                                         \
                                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>                             \
struct Alias_##member;                                                      \
                                                                            \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct Alias_##member <                                                     \
    T, std::integral_constant<bool, got_type<decltype(&T::member)>::value>  \
> { static const decltype(&T::member) value; };                             \
                                                                            \
struct AmbiguitySeed_##member { char member; };                             \
                                                                            \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct has_member_##member {                                                \
    static const bool value                                                 \
        = has_member<                                                       \
            Alias_##member<ambiguate<T, AmbiguitySeed_##member>>            \
            , Alias_##member<AmbiguitySeed_##member>                        \
        >::value                                                            \
    ;                                                                       \
}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member variable with given name.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK(var_name)                                   \
                                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>                             \
struct has_member_var_##var_name : std::false_type {};                      \
                                                                            \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct has_member_var_##var_name<                                           \
    T                                                                       \
    , std::integral_constant<                                               \
        bool                                                                \
        , !std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::var_name)>::value   \
    >                                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_SIG_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member function with given name AND signature.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_SIG_CHECK(func_name, func_sig, templ_postfix)    \
                                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>                             \
struct has_member_func_##templ_postfix : std::false_type {};                \
                                                                            \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct has_member_func_##templ_postfix<                                     \
    T, std::integral_constant<                                              \
        bool                                                                \
        , sig_check<func_sig, &T::func_name>::value                         \
    >                                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member class with given name.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK(class_name)               \
                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>             \
struct has_member_class_##class_name : std::false_type {};  \
                                                            \
template<typename T>                                        \
struct has_member_class_##class_name<                       \
    T                                                       \
    , std::integral_constant<                               \
        bool                                                \
        , std::is_class<                                    \
            typename got_type<typename T::class_name>::type \
        >::value                                            \
    >                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member union with given name.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK(union_name)               \
                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>             \
struct has_member_union_##union_name : std::false_type {};  \
                                                            \
template<typename T>                                        \
struct has_member_union_##union_name<                       \
    T                                                       \
    , std::integral_constant<                               \
        bool                                                \
        , std::is_union<                                    \
            typename got_type<typename T::union_name>::type \
        >::value                                            \
    >                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member enum with given name.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK(enum_name)                 \
                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>             \
struct has_member_enum_##enum_name : std::false_type {};    \
                                                            \
template<typename T>                                        \
struct has_member_enum_##enum_name<                         \
    T                                                       \
    , std::integral_constant<                               \
        bool                                                \
        , std::is_enum<                                     \
            typename got_type<typename T::enum_name>::type  \
        >::value                                            \
    >                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_CHECK:**

```
//Check for function with given name, any signature.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_CHECK(func)          \
template<typename T>                            \
struct has_member_func_##func {                 \
    static const bool value                     \
        = has_member_##func<T>::value           \
        && !has_member_var_##func<T>::value     \
        && !has_member_class_##func<T>::value   \
        && !has_member_union_##func<T>::value   \
        && !has_member_enum_##func<T>::value    \
    ;                                           \
}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_CHECKS:**

```
//Create all the checks for one member.  Does NOT include func sig checks.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_CHECKS(member)    \
CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK(member);            \
CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK(member);        \
CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK(member);      \
CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK(member);      \
CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK(member);       \
CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_CHECK(member)
```

Comment: This is great; it would be nice to put this in a single header file library.

Answer (score 14):

With c++ 20 this becomes much simpler. Say we want to test if a class `T` has a member function `void T::resize(typename T::size_type)`. For example, `std::vector<U>` has such a member function. Then,

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept has_resize_member_func = requires {
    typename T::size_type;
    { std::declval<T>().resize(std::declval<typename T::size_type>()) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};
```

and the usage is

```cpp
static_assert(has_resize_member_func<std::string>, "");
static_assert(has_resize_member_func<int> == false, "");
```

Answer (score 13):

This should be sufficient, if you know the name of the member function you are expecting. (In this case, the function bla fails to instantiate if there is no member function (writing one that works anyway is tough because there is a lack of function partial specialization. You may need to use class templates) Also, the enable struct (which is similar to enable_if) could also be templated on the type of function you want it to have as a member.

```
template <typename T, int (T::*) ()> struct enable { typedef T type; };
template <typename T> typename enable<T, &T::i>::type bla (T&);
struct A { void i(); };
struct B { int i(); };
int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  bla(b);
  bla(a);
}
```

Comment: thaks! it's similar to the solution proposed by yrp. I didn't know that template can be templated over member functions. That's a new feature I've learned today! ... and a new lesson: "never say you are expert on c++" :)

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simpler take on Mike Kinghan's answer. This will detect inherited methods. It will also check for the *exact* signature (unlike jrok's approach which allows argument conversions).

```
template <class C>
class HasGreetMethod
{
    template <class T>
    static std::true_type testSignature(void (T::*)(const char*) const);

    template <class T>
    static decltype(testSignature(&T::greet)) test(std::nullptr_t);

    template <class T>
    static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    using type = decltype(test<C>(nullptr));
    static const bool value = type::value;
};

struct A { void greet(const char* name) const; };
struct Derived : A { };
static_assert(HasGreetMethod<Derived>::value, "");
```

Runnable [example](http://ideone.com/LjtMSi)

Comment: This is good, but it won't work if the function takes no argument

Comment: It does work great. I did not have any problems applying this trick to member functions taking no arguments.

Comment: This works well for me with multiple and no method arguments, including with overloads, and including with inheritance, and with the use of `using` to bring overloads from the base class. It works for me on MSVC 2015 and with Clang-CL. It doesn't work with MSVC 2012 however.

Answer (score 8):

You appear to want the detector idiom.  The above answers are variations on this that work with C++11 or C++14.

The `std::experimental` library has features which do essentially this. Reworking an example from above, it might be:

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

// serialized_method_t is a detector type for T.serialize(int) const
template<typename T>
using serialized_method_t = decltype(std::declval<const T&>().serialize(std::declval<int>()));

// has_serialize_t is std::true_type when T.serialize(int) exists,
// and false otherwise.
template<typename T>
using has_serialize_t = std::experimental::is_detected_t<serialized_method_t, T>;
```

If you can't use std::experimental, a rudimentary version can be made like this:

```
template <typename... Ts>
using void_t = void;
template <template <class...> class Trait, class AlwaysVoid, class... Args>
struct detector : std::false_type {};
template <template <class...> class Trait, class... Args>
struct detector<Trait, void_t<Trait<Args...>>, Args...> : std::true_type {};

// serialized_method_t is a detector type for T.serialize(int) const
template<typename T>
using serialized_method_t = decltype(std::declval<const T&>().serialize(std::declval<int>()));

// has_serialize_t is std::true_type when T.serialize(int) exists,
// and false otherwise.
template <typename T>
using has_serialize_t = typename detector<serialized_method_t, void, T>::type;
```

Since has_serialize_t is really either std::true_type or std::false_type, it can be used via any of the common SFINAE idioms:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<has_serialize_t<T>::value, std::string>
SerializeToString(const T& t) {
}
```

Or by using dispatch with overload resolution:

```
template<class T>
std::string SerializeImpl(std::true_type, const T& t) {
  // call serialize here.
}

template<class T>
std::string SerializeImpl(std::false_type, const T& t) {
  // do something else here.
}

template<class T>
std::string Serialize(const T& t) {
  return SerializeImpl(has_serialize_t<T>{}, t);
}
```

Comment: For modern C++, this is the best answer of the lot.

Comment: This is my favorite answer, but this solution (like many others) only checks that the method can be invoked with a given type. To ensure an exact signature match, use an integral_constant template as Op.

template<class T>
using serialize_method_t = std::integral_constant<void(T::*)(int), &T::serialize>

Answer (score 5):

You can use **[std::is_member_function_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer)**

```
class A {
   public:
     void foo() {};
}

 bool test = std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&A::foo)>::value;
```

Comment: Won't `&A::foo` be a compile error if there's no `foo` at all in `A`?  I read the original question as being supposed to work with any input class, not just ones that have some sort of member named `foo`.

Comment: This does not work. It gives a compile error if the function is not a member of `A`.

Answer (score 5):

Came with the same kind of problem myself, and found the proposed solutions in here very interesting... but had the requirement for a solution that:

1. Detects inherited functions as well;
2. Is compatible with non C++11 ready compilers (so no decltype)

Found another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967183/2200040) proposing something like this, based on a [BOOST discussion](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/01/44538.php).
Here is the generalisation of the proposed solution as two macros declaration for traits class, following the model of [boost::has_*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) classes.

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_class.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

/// Has constant function
/** \param func_ret_type Function return type
    \param func_name Function name
    \param ... Variadic arguments are for the function parameters
*/
#define DECLARE_TRAITS_HAS_FUNC_C(func_ret_type, func_name, ...) \
    __DECLARE_TRAITS_HAS_FUNC(1, func_ret_type, func_name, ##__VA_ARGS__)

/// Has non-const function
/** \param func_ret_type Function return type
    \param func_name Function name
    \param ... Variadic arguments are for the function parameters
*/
#define DECLARE_TRAITS_HAS_FUNC(func_ret_type, func_name, ...) \
    __DECLARE_TRAITS_HAS_FUNC(0, func_ret_type, func_name, ##__VA_ARGS__)

// Traits content
#define __DECLARE_TRAITS_HAS_FUNC(func_const, func_ret_type, func_name, ...)  \
    template                                                                  \
    <   typename Type,                                                        \
        bool is_class = boost::is_class<Type>::value                          \
    >                                                                         \
    class has_func_ ## func_name;                                             \
    template<typename Type>                                                   \
    class has_func_ ## func_name<Type,false>                                  \
    {public:                                                                  \
        BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT( bool, value = false );                         \
        typedef boost::false_type type;                                       \
    };                                                                        \
    template<typename Type>                                                   \
    class has_func_ ## func_name<Type,true>                                   \
    {   struct yes { char _foo; };                                            \
        struct no { yes _foo[2]; };                                           \
        struct Fallback                                                       \
        {   func_ret_type func_name( __VA_ARGS__ )                            \
                UTILITY_OPTIONAL(func_const,const) {}                         \
        };                                                                    \
        struct Derived : public Type, public Fallback {};                     \
        template <typename T, T t>  class Helper{};                           \
        template <typename U>                                                 \
        static no deduce(U*, Helper                                           \
            <   func_ret_type (Fallback::*)( __VA_ARGS__ )                    \
                    UTILITY_OPTIONAL(func_const,const),                       \
                &U::func_name                                                 \
            >* = 0                                                            \
        );                                                                    \
        static yes deduce(...);                                               \
    public:                                                                   \
        BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(                                                \
            bool,                                                             \
            value = sizeof(yes)                                               \
                == sizeof( deduce( static_cast<Derived*>(0) ) )               \
        );                                                                    \
        typedef ::boost::integral_constant<bool,value> type;                  \
        BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, is_const = func_const);                   \
        typedef func_ret_type return_type;                                    \
        typedef ::boost::mpl::vector< __VA_ARGS__ > args_type;                \
    }

// Utility functions
#define UTILITY_OPTIONAL(condition, ...) UTILITY_INDIRECT_CALL( __UTILITY_OPTIONAL_ ## condition , ##__VA_ARGS__ )
#define UTILITY_INDIRECT_CALL(macro, ...) macro ( __VA_ARGS__ )
#define __UTILITY_OPTIONAL_0(...)
#define __UTILITY_OPTIONAL_1(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

These macros expand to a traits class with the following prototype:

```
template<class T>
class has_func_[func_name]
{
public:
    /// Function definition result value
    /** Tells if the tested function is defined for type T or not.
    */
    static const bool value = true | false;

    /// Function definition result type
    /** Type representing the value attribute usable in
        http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html
    */
    typedef boost::integral_constant<bool,value> type;

    /// Tested function constness indicator
    /** Indicates if the tested function is const or not.
        This value is not deduced, it is forced depending
        on the user call to one of the traits generators.
    */
    static const bool is_const = true | false;

    /// Tested function return type
    /** Indicates the return type of the tested function.
        This value is not deduced, it is forced depending
        on the user's arguments to the traits generators.
    */
    typedef func_ret_type return_type;

    /// Tested function arguments types
    /** Indicates the arguments types of the tested function.
        This value is not deduced, it is forced depending
        on the user's arguments to the traits generators.
    */
    typedef ::boost::mpl::vector< __VA_ARGS__ > args_type;
};
```

So what is the typical usage one can do out of this?

```
// We enclose the traits class into
// a namespace to avoid collisions
namespace ns_0 {
    // Next line will declare the traits class
    // to detect the member function void foo(int,int) const
    DECLARE_TRAITS_HAS_FUNC_C(void, foo, int, int);
}

// we can use BOOST to help in using the traits
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

// Here is a function that is active for types
// declaring the good member function
template<typename T> inline
typename boost::enable_if< ns_0::has_func_foo<T> >::type
foo_bar(const T &_this_, int a=0, int b=1)
{   _this_.foo(a,b);
}

// Here is a function that is active for types
// NOT declaring the good member function
template<typename T> inline
typename boost::disable_if< ns_0::has_func_foo<T> >::type
foo_bar(const T &_this_, int a=0, int b=1)
{   default_foo(_this_,a,b);
}

// Let us declare test types
struct empty
{
};
struct direct_foo
{
    void foo(int,int);
};
struct direct_const_foo
{
    void foo(int,int) const;
};
struct inherited_const_foo :
    public direct_const_foo
{
};

// Now anywhere in your code you can seamlessly use
// the foo_bar function on any object:
void test()
{
    int a;
    foo_bar(a); // calls default_foo

    empty b;
    foo_bar(b); // calls default_foo

    direct_foo c;
    foo_bar(c); // calls default_foo (member function is not const)

    direct_const_foo d;
    foo_bar(d); // calls d.foo (member function is const)

    inherited_const_foo e;
    foo_bar(e); // calls e.foo (inherited member function)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To accomplish this we'll need to use:

1. [Function template overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) with differing return types according to whether the method is available
2. In keeping with the meta-conditionals in the [`type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header, we'll want to return a [`true_type` or `false_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) from our overloads
3. Declare the `true_type` overload expecting an `int` and the `false_type` overload expecting Variadic Parameters to exploit: ["The lowest priority of the ellipsis conversion in overload resolution"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Notes)
4. In defining the template specification for the `true_type` function we will use [`declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) and [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) allowing us to detect the function independent of return type differences or overloads between methods

**You can see a live example of this [here](http://ideone.com/mi5JKQ).** But I'll also explain it below:

I want to check for the existence of a function named `test` which takes a type convertible from `int`, then I'd need to declare these two functions:

```
template <typename T, typename S = decltype(declval<T>().test(declval<int>))> static true_type hasTest(int);
template <typename T> static false_type hasTest(...);
```

- `decltype(hasTest<a>(0))::value` is `true` (Note there is no need to create special functionality to deal with the `void a::test()` overload, the `void a::test(int)` is accepted)
- `decltype(hasTest<b>(0))::value` is `true` (Because `int` is convertable to `double` `int b::test(double)` is accepted, independent of return type)
- `decltype(hasTest<c>(0))::value` is `false` (`c` does not have a method named `test` that accepts a type convertible from `int` therefor this is not accepted)

This solution has 2 drawbacks:

1. Requires a per method declaration of a pair of functions
2. Creates namespace pollution particularly if we want to test for similar names, for example what would we name a function that wanted to test for a `test()` method?

So it's important that these functions be declared in a details namespace, or ideally if they are only to be used with a class, they should be declared privately by that class. To that end I've written a macro to help you abstract this information:

```
#define FOO(FUNCTION, DEFINE) template <typename T, typename S = decltype(declval<T>().FUNCTION)> static true_type __ ## DEFINE(int); \
                              template <typename T> static false_type __ ## DEFINE(...); \
                              template <typename T> using DEFINE = decltype(__ ## DEFINE<T>(0));
```

You could use this like:

```
namespace details {
    FOO(test(declval<int>()), test_int)
    FOO(test(), test_void)
}
```

Subsequently calling `details::test_int<a>::value` or `details::test_void<a>::value` would yield `true` or `false` for the purposes of inline code or meta-programming.

Answer (score 4):

To be non-intrusive, you can also put `serialize` in the namespace of the class being serialised, or of the archive class, thanks to [Koenig lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenig_lookup). See [Namespaces for Free Function Overrides](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#namespaces) for more details. :-)

Opening up any given namespace to implement a free function is Simply Wrong. (e.g., you're not supposed to open up namespace `std` to implement `swap` for your own types, but should use Koenig lookup instead.)

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Second try. It's okay if you don't like this one either, I'm looking for more ideas.

Herb Sutter's article talks about traits. So you can have a traits class whose default instantiation has the fallback behaviour, and for each class where your member function exists, then the traits class is specialised to invoke the member function. I believe Herb's article mentions a technique to do this so that it doesn't involve lots of copying and pasting.

Like I said, though, perhaps you don't want the extra work involved with "tagging" classes that do implement that member. In which case, I'm looking at a third solution....

Comment: eh... I've analyzed this solution... I think it's a little bit too expensive for users of my framework. (ok, I admit, I'm developing a streaming framework and I'm choosing between extending iostream or rewriting something easier)

Comment: My third solution would be to use SFINAE. Since yrp's answer already mentions it, I won't go into it (because I'm still researching on it: I know the idea, but the devil is in the details), unless his solution doesn't work for you in the end. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using facebook folly, there are out of box macro to help you:

```
#include <folly/Traits.h>
namespace {
  FOLLY_CREATE_HAS_MEMBER_FN_TRAITS(has_test_traits, test);
} // unnamed-namespace

void some_func() {
  cout << "Does class Foo have a member int test() const? "
    << boolalpha << has_test_traits<Foo, int() const>::value;
}
```

Though the implementation details is the same with the previous answer, use a library is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need and came across o this SO. There are many interesting/powerful solutions proposed here, though it is a bit long for just a specific need : detect if a class has member function with a precise signature. So I did some reading/testing and came up with my version that could be of interest. It detect :

- static member function
- non-static member function
- non-static member function const

with a precise signature. Since I don't need to capture *any* signature (that'd require a more complicated solution), this one suites to me. It basically used **enable_if_t**.

```
struct Foo{ static int sum(int, const double&){return 0;} };
struct Bar{ int calc(int, const double&) {return 1;} };
struct BarConst{ int calc(int, const double&) const {return 1;} };

// Note : second typename can be void or anything, as long as it is consistent with the result of enable_if_t
template<typename T, typename = T> struct has_static_sum : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct has_static_sum<typename T,
                        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(T::sum), int(int, const double&)>::value,T> 
                      > : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = T> struct has_calc : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct has_calc <typename T,
                  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(&T::calc), int(T::*)(int, const double&)>::value,T>
                > : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = T> struct has_calc_const : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct has_calc_const <T,
                        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(&T::calc), int(T::*)(int, const double&) const>::value,T>
                      > : std::true_type {};

int main ()
{
    constexpr bool has_sum_val = has_static_sum<Foo>::value;
    constexpr bool not_has_sum_val = !has_static_sum<Bar>::value;

    constexpr bool has_calc_val = has_calc<Bar>::value;
    constexpr bool not_has_calc_val = !has_calc<Foo>::value;

    constexpr bool has_calc_const_val = has_calc_const<BarConst>::value;
    constexpr bool not_has_calc_const_val = !has_calc_const<Bar>::value;

    std::cout<< "           has_sum_val " << has_sum_val            << std::endl
             << "       not_has_sum_val " << not_has_sum_val        << std::endl
             << "          has_calc_val " << has_calc_val           << std::endl
             << "      not_has_calc_val " << not_has_calc_val       << std::endl
             << "    has_calc_const_val " << has_calc_const_val     << std::endl
             << "not_has_calc_const_val " << not_has_calc_const_val << std::endl;
}
```

Output :

```
           has_sum_val 1
       not_has_sum_val 1
          has_calc_val 1
      not_has_calc_val 1
    has_calc_const_val 1
not_has_calc_const_val 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Without C++11 support (`decltype`) this might work:

## SSCCE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A { void foo(void); };
struct Aa: public A { };
struct B { };

struct retA { int foo(void); };
struct argA { void foo(double); };
struct constA { void foo(void) const; };
struct varA { int foo; };

template<typename T>
struct FooFinder {
    typedef char true_type[1];
    typedef char false_type[2];

    template<int>
    struct TypeSink;

    template<class U>
    static true_type &match(U);

    template<class U>
    static true_type &test(TypeSink<sizeof( matchType<void (U::*)(void)>( &U::foo ) )> *);

    template<class U>
    static false_type &test(...);

    enum { value = (sizeof(test<T>(0, 0)) == sizeof(true_type)) };
};

int main() {
    cout << FooFinder<A>::value << endl;
    cout << FooFinder<Aa>::value << endl;
    cout << FooFinder<B>::value << endl;

    cout << FooFinder<retA>::value << endl;
    cout << FooFinder<argA>::value << endl;
    cout << FooFinder<constA>::value << endl;
    cout << FooFinder<varA>::value << endl;
}
```

## How it hopefully works

`A`, `Aa` and `B` are the clases in question, `Aa` being the special one that inherits the member we're looking for.

In the `FooFinder` the `true_type` and `false_type` are the replacements for the correspondent C++11 classes. Also for the understanding of template meta programming, they reveal the very basis of the SFINAE-sizeof-trick.

The `TypeSink` is a template struct that is used later to sink the integral result of the `sizeof` operator into a template instantiation to form a type.

The `match` function is another SFINAE kind of template that is left without a generic counterpart. It can hence only be instantiated if the type of its argument matches the type it was specialized for.

Both the `test` functions together with the enum declaration finally form the central SFINAE pattern. There is a generic one using an ellipsis that returns the `false_type` and a counterpart with more specific arguments to take precedence.

To be able to instantiate the `test` function with a template argument of `T`, the `match` function must be instantiated, as its return type is required to instantiate the `TypeSink` argument. The caveat is that `&U::foo`, being wrapped in a function argument, is *not* referred to from within a template argument specialization, so inherited member lookup still takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947836/jrok)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824239/2379665), I have avoided using nested template classes and/or functions.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

#define CHECK_NESTED_FUNC(fName) \
    template <typename, typename, typename = std::void_t<>> \
    struct _has_##fName \
    : public std::false_type {}; \
    \
    template <typename Class, typename Ret, typename... Args> \
    struct _has_##fName<Class, Ret(Args...), \
        std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Class>().fName(std::declval<Args>()...))>> \
    : public std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<Class>().fName(std::declval<Args>()...)), Ret> \
    {}; \
    \
    template <typename Class, typename Signature> \
    using has_##fName = _has_##fName<Class, Signature>;

#define HAS_NESTED_FUNC(Class, Func, Signature) has_##Func<Class, Signature>::value
```

We can use the above macros as below:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar(int, const char *) {}
};

CHECK_NESTED_FUNC(Bar);  // generate required metafunctions

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << boolalpha
         << HAS_NESTED_FUNC(Foo, Bar, void(int, const char *))  // prints true
         << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Suggestions are welcome.