# check for whether a type instance can be streamed

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I've puzzled over this meta-function for a long time. It seems to work, but I suspect it to contain UB, when it checks for size of a possibly undefined reference type? Is there a problem with this meta-function?

```
template <class S, class C, typename = void>
struct is_streamable : ::std::false_type { };

template <class S, class C>
struct is_streamable<S,
  C,
  decltype(void(sizeof(decltype(::std::declval<S&>() <<
    ::std::declval<C const&>()))))
> : ::std::true_type
{
};
```

EDIT: The motivation for my question (and worries) was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711952/how-to-detect-existence-of-a-class-using-sfinae). Why did he not use a similar trick (checking size of a reference type)?

Comment: your trait fails if `operator<<` of streamable object returns `void`. why are you checking decltype of sizeof of expression, casted to void, instead of using just the voidified decltype of expression?

Comment: @PiotrS. Good idea! I think I did it precisely because the streaming instances (ostream const&) should not return void.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

> when it checks for size of a possibly undefined reference type?

That never induces UB. It would just result in a deduction failure (according to [temp.deduct]/8), causing the *primary* template to be instantiated. [expr.sizeof]:

> When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the
>   size of the referenced type.

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   […] incomplete type […].

But a yet incomplete `ostream` is regarded "streamable" for a `string` if the global `operator<<` is overloaded. 
To fix that,  define the partial specialization as

```
template <class S, class C>
struct is_streamable<S, C,
    decltype(void( std::declval<S&>() << std::declval<C const&>() ))
    > : ::std::true_type
{};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e07ddaddd443b73f).

Comment: And I haven't commited any other non-portable offense or UB?

Comment: @user1095108 I only know saw what the problem with your code is. It should work for an incomplete `ostream` with defined `operator<<`. Changed my answer appropriately, check the demo.