# gcc 6.1 std::result_of compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, result-of, gcc6

Consider a small standalone use case wherein I want to determine if a type is a complete or incomplete using

```
#include <type_traits>
namespace {

struct foo {
    template<class T, std::size_t = sizeof(T)>
    std::false_type  operator()(T&);
    std::true_type operator()(...);
};

struct FooIncomplete;
}


int main() {
    std::result_of<foo(FooIncomplete&)>::type();

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine with `gcc 4.9.3` with `--std=c++11` flag. However, with `gcc 6.1` and `--std=c++11` it produces a [compilation error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74ffb08452992c7a) as

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:5: error: 'type' is not a member of 'std::result_of<{anonymous}::foo({anonymous}::FooIncomplete&)>'
     std::result_of<foo(FooIncomplete&)>::type();
```

What am I missing here ? What could be a possible work around ?

Comment: Looks like a g++ regression

Comment: @Arunmu Should g++ pick `operator()(...)` then ? It attempts to make a copy of an incomplete type

Comment: Did you try it without anonymous `namespace`, i.e. using a named one instead.

Comment: Have you considered what happens (under the standard) when two `FooIncomplete` is complete in one context but not another, and both try your trick?  I don't think the result is ... good.

Comment: Possible workaround is to SFINAE-probe for the existence of `FooIncomplete::~FooIncomplete`.
See [How to detect existence of a class using SFINAE?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711952/1362568)

Answer (score 0):

Since C++14 result_of::type doesn't exist if T is not callable.

In your case struct FooIncomplete has nothing to call.

Comment: OP tries to invoke `foo::operator()`, not `FooIncomplete`

Answer (score 0):

Using something like C++20's `is_detected`:

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=typename details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>::type;

template<class T>
using size_of = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(T)>;

template<class T>
using is_complete = can_apply< size_of, T >;
```

we get a trait `is_complete` that is true iff we can apply `sizeof` to `T`.

Be careful with this, because unlike most features the completeness of a type can change between compilation units and even at different spots in the same unit.  And C++ doesn't *like* it when the type `some_template<some_args...>` changes at different spots in your program.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4f3ca8fbacc4de2).