# GCC 9.1 returns void& as result type for an explicit destructor call. Is this a bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++17

I'm trying to get [this is-class-defined-check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722840/4694124) to work, which relies on the fact that `decltype(std::declval<Foo>().~Foo())` is `void` if `Foo` has a destructor (which it has if it is defined…) and is ill-formed otherwise, invoking SFINAE in this case.

However, I can't get the code to work with GCC 9.1, and that is because GCC 9.1 seems to consider that type to be `void &` *if the destructor is defaulted*, consider this example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo {
public:
// With this, the DestructorReturnType below becomes "void"
//    ~Foo () {} 
};

// … unless I specify the user-defined destructor above, in which case it is "void"
using DestructorReturnType = decltype(std::declval<Foo>().~Foo());

template<class T>
class TD;

// Says: aggregate 'TD<void&> t' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
TD<DestructorReturnType> t;
```

(available at https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K1TjOP )

If I user-define an empty destructor, the type jumps back to `void`. Also if I switch back to GCC 8.x.

The C++17 standard states in [expr.call]:

> If the postfix-expression designates a destructor, the type of the function call expression is void; […]

Because of all this, I suspect that GCC 8.x (and clang, …) are correct, and GCC 9.1 is just wrong. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, clear bug, per the wording you site. Also, `void&` isn't even a real type, you can't take a reference to `void`. Please file.

Comment: Has GCC implemented regular void by accident? /s

Comment: Already on there as [90598](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90598).

Comment: Oh wait that was you haha

Comment: Yes, excited for my first self-discovered GCC bug. ;-)

Comment: And there I was, excited to have found it in the DB ‍♂️

Comment: Seems like you could turn the last part of the question into an answer

Comment: lol... Probably a side-effect of language people pretending that ctor/dtor isn't a function (trying to treat object and memory it occupies as one "entity") and compiler writers who see through this and understand that ctor/dtor is the same function like any other

Comment: Thank you for submitting a bug report. Most people would just find a workaround and move on. You didn't - you did the work / right thing that means we will all benefit from a future fix to this bug. Thank you for doing that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long story short: [Yes, this is a regression in GCC 9.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90598). `void&` is not even a valid type, so something is very wrong. Apparrently, the problem can be worked around by setting the `-fno-lifetime-dse` compiler option, at the (possible, slight) expense  of performance. Also, GCC versions before 9.1 are not affected.

If you find this answer because you are also trying to implement the is-class-defined-check above, I think that [the much simpler form using sizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594334/4694124) should be well-defined, work and is not hit by this bug.

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept your own answer; obviously it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I have to wait for two days.