# Overload that still compiles if parameter type doesn't exist

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I have a function like so:

```
template <typename T>
void modify(T& x) {
  ...
}
```

I would like to add an overload specialized for the type `Foo`, like so:

```cpp
void modify(Foo& x) {
  ...
}
```

However, this poses the problem that this definition will fail to compile if the type `Foo` doesn't exist, but I'd like this header to still compile in that case, just with that overload (logically) omitted. After all, the `Foo` overload won't be useful if the user hasn't included a definition of that type.

Comment: Does your application allow the type to be registered somehow? Then it becomes an easy task. Otherwise I don't think it's doable.

Comment: Does the header file that defines `__m256i` #define something (maybe an include guard)?  If so, you could `#ifdef` (gasp) off that.  Might not be very portable though,

Comment: @PaulSanders - let's say it doesn't. I don't want to check any macro anyway because this would then depend on the include order: if this function was in a header included before the one that defines `__m256i` this would fail to include the overload.

Comment: @davidhigh - it seems doable with SFINAE: we can exclude the overload if the `__m256i` type does not exist. The problem is then that the two overloads (the original and `__m256i` specific one might then both be equally suitable resulting in an ambiguity.

Comment: _if this function was in a header included before the one that defines __m256i this would fail to include the overload_ If you want the overload to compile / exist then the header file defining `__m256i` must be included first, no?

Comment: @PaulSanders - I dislike the idea, yes, because there is no _reliable_ define like that, and it's not a generic solution: I would need to look for a suitable define for every type, and if the type was unknown it wouldn't work. Yes, the function as written would fail if the include order was wrong: part of the trick is to fix this: to defer the type lookup until instantiation. I believe this needs SFINAE or similar. The point of this approach is to avoid dragging in a giant header that 95% of users won't care about (and some won't even have), but to support that type for the other 5%.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Even if you could SFINAE your way there, you would invariably have to declare something called `__m256i` in the process, which is illegal by virtue of starting with 2 underscore. So It's going to get pretty ugly anyways if you want to go there,

Comment: @Frank - perhaps `__m256i` was a bad example, my question really applies to any type. I'll change it to `Foo` to avoid this double underscore issue which I don't think is core to the issue.

Comment: @Frank - that said, I'm surprised I would have to declare something called `__m256i` in any case? I would expect to use something like "if exists __m256i, include this overload" (where I'll be using the existing definition) and "if not, don't include it" (where I won't have to refer to __m256i).

Comment: C++ has no 'if type xxx exists' construct, unfortunately.  It would need compiler support and it just isn't there.

Comment: "`if exists __m256i`": the problem with that is that `__m256i` needs to refer to something in order to make that comparison. You unfortunately can't compare against a name by itself, it has to be a name that refers to something.

Comment: @PaulSanders - what about something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876264/149138) or [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190711-00/?p=102682)?

Comment: @BeeOnRope Both of these rely on the type being testing being a type that can be incomplete, which is not the case here.

Comment: [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711952/how-to-detect-existence-of-a-class-using-sfinae/26876264#26876264) problem is you cannot actually use `A` afterwards, only `::A`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd8ebac5cb93a599

Comment: Whey are you trying to overload `method(Foo &)` for a non-existant `Foo`?.    In any event, a *declaration* (not a definition) of `Foo` is needed to declare such a `method()`.   The definition of `method()`, if it doesn't use its argument, does not require `Foo` to be defined either.   But, if `method()` uses the passed `Foo()`, `Foo` must be defined.     Also, to call such a function, the caller must be able to instantiate `Foo` in order to pass an object by reference (or to initialise a reference, since creating a reference that does not refer to an object is a diagnosable error).

Comment: @Peter - basically `Foo` is declared in a 100,000-line header file. I don't want to include this header in the standalone utility header that declares `modify` if the user will never use the `Foo` overload. However, if the user _does_ already include that header themselves, they should be able to use the overload I provide. So the caller will not have any problem instantiating with `Foo`. The body of `modify` is generic, it does not really depend on details of `Foo`. The `modify` overload will probably have to be a template, which sort of solves the concerns in the second half of your comment.

Comment: That is, if gets instantiated in the first place (by a call passing a `Foo&`), there will be a declaration of `Foo` in scope so compiling the function will proceed w/o issue.

Comment: If you can somehow get compile-time constant `Foo_is_defined` you could at least just use `void modify(T& x) { if constexpr(Foo_is_defined) { if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Foo>) { ... /* T is Foo actions */ return; } } ... /* T is not Foo actions */ }` without additional overload needed but I doubt you can even get `Foo_is_defined`

Answer (score 0):

A non-portable hackish solution is to use ifdefs checking for the Foo header include guard (which might change, or it might be using `#pragma once`). Also this requires the Foo header be included before your header in a translation unit.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void modify(T& x) {
  ...
}

#ifdef FOO_H
template<>
void modify(Foo &x) {
  ...
}
#endif
```

Another cleaner option if you have the option to use source files, is to forward declare Foo in your header, then in the modify function, call another function defined in a source file which has the full knowledge of Foo:

```
// your header
template<typename T>
void modify(T &a) {
    ...
}

class Foo;

void modify_foo(Foo &a);

template<>
void modify(Foo &a) {
    modify_foo(a);
}
```

```cpp
// some source file
#include "foo.h"

void modify_foo(Foo &a) {
    ...
}
```