# CRTP Dispatch in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, crtp

Say I have the following code:

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
public:
   virtual void foo_impl() = 0;
   void foo() {
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_impl(); //A
      (*static_cast<Derived*>(this)).foo_impl(); //B
   }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
private:
   void foo_impl() {
      bar();
   }
};
```

A few questions:

Will line A generate a virtual function call?  Although the majority of what I can find on the internet recommends doing things this way, to me I don't see how the compiler can do static dispatch considering that a pointer to Derived could still actually point to an object of type Derived2 where Derived2 : public Derived.

Does line B fix the issue I brought up in my previous point (if applicable)?  It seems like it would, considering that now the call is not on a pointer any more and thus using *. would avoid a virtual function call.  But if the compiler treats the dereferenced cast as a reference type, it could still generate a virtual function call... in that case, what is the workaround?

Does adding the C++11 final keyword to foo_impl() change how the compiler would act in either (or any other relevant) case?

Comment: Statements A and B are 100% equivalent, by definition of the built-in `->` operator.

Comment: Statements A and B are 100% equivalent to `foo_impl();`.  The extra verbiage is just that.

Comment: The call is not on a pointer, but rather on an lvalue reference - as said, identical semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will line A generate a virtual function call?

**Yes**. `foo_impl()` is virtual and `Derived` overrides it. Even though `foo_impl()` in `Derived` is not *explicitly* tagged as `virtual`, it is in the base class, and this is enough to make it a virtual function.

> Does line B fix the issue I brought up in my previous point (if applicable)?

**No**. It does not matter if the call is on a pointer or on a reference: the compiler still won't know whether you are invoking the function `foo_impl()` on an instance of a class that *derives from* `Derived`, or on a direct instance of `Derived`. Thus, the call is performed through a vtable.

To see what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Derived>
class Base {
public:
   virtual void foo_impl() = 0;
   void foo() {
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_impl();
      (*static_cast<Derived*>(this)).foo_impl();
   }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
   void foo_impl() {
      cout << "Derived::foo_impl()" << endl;
   }
};

class MoreDerived : public Derived {
public:
   void foo_impl() {
      cout << "MoreDerived::foo_impl()" << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
    MoreDerived d;
    d.foo(); // Will output "MoreDerived::foo_impl()" twice
}
```

Finally:

> Does adding the C++11 final keyword to `foo_impl()` change how the compiler would act in either (or any other relevant) case?

**In theory,  yes**. The `final` keyword would make it impossible to override that function in subclasses of `Derived`. Thus, when performing a function call to `foo_impl()` through a pointer to `Derived`, the compiler *could* resolve the call statically. However, to the best of my knowledge, compilers are not *required* to do so by the C++ Standard.

**CONCLUSION**:

In any case, I believe what you actually want to do is **not to declare** the `foo_impl()` function at all in the base class. This is normally the case when you use the CRTP. Additionally, you will have to declare class `Base<Derived>` a `friend` of `Derived` if you want it to access `Derived`'s `private` function `foo_impl()`. Otherwise, you can make `foo_impl()` public.

Comment: I think that when the function is declared `final` the compiler might have enough information to make a static call rather than a virtual, as an optimization. Don't know how likely that is though.

Comment: OK, then is there any way to enforce the interface on the subclass without C++ concepts?  Perhaps the expression SFINAE or static_assert?  I've seen what some of the error messages can look like...

Comment: @MarkRansom: Hm, good point. I am not sure whether compilers are guaranteed to do so though. I need to check in the standard.

Comment: @RobertMason: You mean, to enforce a non-virtual dispatch? If so, just avoid declaring `foo_impl()` as virtual in the base class.

Comment: @RobertMason: If the program *uses* `Base<T>::foo`, then the compiler will gladly scream that `Derived::foo_impl` is not declared. What else do you need? You can disable dynamic dispatch (added an answer with the *how*), but the real question is whether you really need the extra vptr and complexity for anything at all, or whether you are complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: The point is that the compiler will gladly *scream*.  Template errors suck.  I'm not sure if it would be any better to do `typename std::result_of<Derived::foo_impl()>::type foo()` though.  Seems like it would barf just as bad.  The real solution is to use clang, which actually gives you comprehensible errors, but GCC is too widespread... The only purpose of the pure virtual function was to enforce that classes overrode `foo_impl()`, not to actually make function calls - to provide an interface without concepts.

Comment: @RobertMason: You do enforce that automatically by having the function call to `foo_impl()` in the `Base` class. If you are bothered by the lengthiness of the error message, that's another story. I would not change the design of a software drastically just because the error message is hard to understand. As you said, switch to another compiler. Or if you cannot do that, use [concept-like SFINAE techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature) and `static_assert()` to check for the existence of those methods.

Comment: @RobertMason: Also note that reading error messages (including those from templates) is a craft, and you need to train it.

Answer (score 3):

The common idiom for the CRTP does not involve declaring the pure virtual functions in the base. As you mention in one of the comments, that means that the compiler will not enforce the definition of the member in the derived type (other than through *use*, if there is any use of `foo` in the base, that requires the presence of `foo_impl` in the derived type).

While I would stick to the common idiom and not define the pure virtual function in the base, but, if you really feel you need to do it, you can disable dynamic dispatch by adding extra qualification:

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
public:
   virtual void foo_impl() = 0;
   void foo() {
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->Derived::foo_impl();
      //                           ^^^^^^^^^
   }
};
```

The use of the extra qualification `Derived::` disables dynamic dispatch, and that call will be statically resolved to `Derived::foo_impl`. Note that this comes will all of the usual caveats: you have a class with a virtual function and paying the cost of the virtual pointer per object, but you cannot override that virtual function in a most derived type, as the *use* in the CRTP base is blocking dynamic dispatch...

Answer (score 1):

The extra verbiage in lines A and B have absolutely no effect on
the generated code.  I don't know who recommends this (I've never seen
it), but in practice, the only time it might have an effect is
if the function isn't virtual.  Just write `foo_impl()`, and be
done with it.

There *is* a means of avoiding the virtual function call if the
compiler knows the derived type.  I've seen it used for 
vector-like classes (where there are different implementations,
e.g. normal, sparse, etc. of the vector):

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
private:
    virtual T& getValue( int index ) = 0;
public:
    T& operator[]( int index ) { return getValue( index ); }
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
private:
    virtual T& getValue( int index )
    {
        return operator[]( index );
    }
public:
    T& operator[]( index )
    {
        //  find element and return it.
    }
};
```

The idea here is that you normally only work through references
to the base class, but if performance becomes an issue, because
you're using `[]` in a tight loop, you can `dynamic_cast` to the
derived class before the loop, and use `[]` on the derived
class.

Comment: He is mixing and matching what he has read with his own particular wants. The static cast is common for CRTP where the base does *not* have a virtual function. The pure virtual function was added to the base to enforce the implementation of the function in the derived type...