# Correct signature of / detect presence of Container::reserve()

Tags: c++, c++11, std, enable-if

Given a type `C` which is an STL-conforming container, how do I correctly detect if `C` contains a member function `reserve`? I tried the following approach (with GCC 4.6.3):

```
template< typename C, typename = void >
struct has_reserve
  : std::false_type
{};

template< typename C >
struct has_reserve< C, typename std::enable_if<
                         std::is_same<
                           decltype( &C::reserve ),
                           void (C::*)( typename C::size_type )
                         >::value
                       >::type >
  : std::true_type
{};
```

This works for `C` being `std::vector`, but not for the unordered containers, e.g. `std::unordered_set`. The reason is, that `reserve` is a (direct) member function of `std::vector`, but for the unordered containers it is inherited from a base class, i.e., its signature is not `void (C::*)( typename C::size_type )` but `void (B::*)( typename C::size_type )` for some unspecified base class `B` of `C`.

I know how to work around it and detect `reserve` even if inherited, but it looks clumsy and I wonder what is allowed by the standard. So...

My question is: Does the standard allow `reserve` to be inherited from an unspecified base class or is the synopsis binding and requires a direct member function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the standard says about inheritance from base classes is that it is allowed:

> #### 17.6.5.11 Derived classes [derivation]
>
> 1 - An implementation may derive any class in the C++ standard library from a class with a name reserved to the implementation.

It doesn't say either way whether methods (and, indeed, other members such as typedefs) are allowed to be inherited from a base class; obviously, since implementations do so, the standard should describe this behaviour.

In any case, detecting e.g. `reserve` by cast to a member function type is not guaranteed to work even if a member of the most derived type, since:

> #### 17.6.5.5 Member functions [member.functions]
>
> 2 - An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class:
>
> - by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature<sup>186</sup>; [...]
>
> 186) Hence, the address of a member function of a class in the C++ standard library has an unspecified type.

The correct way to check whether `reserve` exists is to attempt to call it:

```
template< typename C, typename = void >
struct has_reserve
  : std::false_type
{};

template< typename C >
struct has_reserve< C, typename std::enable_if<
                         std::is_same<
                           decltype( std::declval<C>().reserve( std::declval<typename C::size_type>() ) ),
                           void
                         >::value
                       >::type >
  : std::true_type
{};
```

This has the advantage of paralleling the container *requirements* (table 103 for `unordered_set`), which are normative where the synopses tend more to the informative.

Comment: Does not compile under VS2012.  Is there an alternative that will?