# Adding element to back of STL container

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

I'm looking for a general way of adding an element to the back of an STL container.  I would like the code to support as many types of STL container as possible.  The following piece of code demonstrates my problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class S {
  T built;
  typename T::iterator built_it;
public:
  S() : built{}, built_it{built.end()} {}
  void add_to(typename T::value_type e) {
    built.emplace(built_it, e);
    ++built_it;
  }
  const T& get() {
    return built;
  }
};

int main()
{ 
  S<std::vector<int>> e;
  S<std::string> f;
  e.add_to(3);   // works
  f.add_to('c'); // doesn't
}
```

The problem here is subtle.  This code works great for `vector`s, because `std::vector` implements the `emplace` function.  But `std::string` does not!  Is there a more general way to perform the same operation?

Comment: Why not use `push_back` instead of `emplace`?  `push_back` is supported by both and seems to better match what you are trying to do.

Comment: `push_back` is not supported by the likes of `std::list`.  I suppose that might be an effective compromise though.

Comment: `push_back` is supported by `std::list`:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/

Comment: Er, whoops!  Thanks, I'll try this and see how far I get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most [generic way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (not necessarily the most efficient way) is:

```
c.insert( c.end(), value );
```

where, of course, `value` needs to be suitable for the container `c` (you may use `decltype(c)::value_type`). In case of an associative container, e.g. `map`, it is a `std::pair`.

This works for *all* standard containers except for `std::forward_list`. For some containers the element is then added at the end, for some the `c.end()` is just a hint that might be ignored.

---

As a follow up to the comments, here's the advanced stuff ;)

When you want to insert **a known number of elements** into a given container `c` (of type `C`) and you want to be at least somewhat efficient, you should detect wether the container type supports `reserve()` and call it before inserting elements.

The following method [detects `reserve()` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882588) (the link explains how):

```
template< typename C, typename = void >
struct has_reserve
  : std::false_type
{};

template< typename C >
struct has_reserve< C, std::enable_if_t<
                         std::is_same<
                           decltype( std::declval<C>().reserve( std::declval<typename C::size_type>() ) ),
                           void
                         >::value
                       > >
  : std::true_type
{};
```

Now you can use it with `std::enable_if_t` to optionally reserve space. An example could look like this:

```
template< typename C >
std::enable_if_t< !has_reserve< C >::value >
optional_reserve( C&, std::size_t ) {}

template< typename C >
std::enable_if_t< has_reserve< C >::value >
optional_reserve( C& c, std::size_t n )
{
  c.reserve( c.size() + n );
}

template< typename C, typename T, std::size_t N >
void add_array( C& c, const std::array< T, N >& a )
{
  optional_reserve( c, N );
  for( const auto& e : a ) {
    c.insert( c.end(), typename C::value_type( e ) ); // see remark below
  }
}
```

`add_array` can now be called with all standard containers (except `std::forward_list`) and it will call `reserve()` for `std::vector` and the unordered associative containers.

As the above does not need explicit specialization or overloading for specific container types, it also works for non-standard containers as long as their interfaces are designed reasonably similar to the standard containers' interfaces. (In fact I had several such "home-made" containers in the past and the above Just-Works™)

A remark about the conversion in the above code: The reason for converting the `T`s to `C::value_type` is just to show that this would be the correct place if it is needed. In the above example it might look superfluous, but in my real-world code I call a special conversion traits class to convert the `e`s (which are encoded strings) into the correct value type for any container.

Comment: Works for the the no-so-standard string container too. :) I suspect it wouldn't be any less efficient than push_back() with a decent compiler and library

Comment: If I keep an iterator as state info, as I'm doing in my sample code above, this would be as efficient as `push_back`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ah, except for when I use a `vector` and it invalidates iterators by reallocating :/.  Then it's dangerous!

Comment: @thirtythreeforty It wouldn't be generic anymore as a `std::list` is quite different than, say, `std::set`. You can not simply advance the iterator in all cases. (And I see you already found the problem with `std::vector` :)  But I wouldn't worry about the performance too much, if you need generic code, the above with `c.end()` is the way to go.

Comment: The compiler will almost certainly inline c.end() so it will be equivalent to reaching directly inside the container's end pointer or size value - however it's been implemented there's not likely to be a function call involved and trying to hold that information yourself is simply duplicating information and a possible source of error

Comment: @thirtythreeforty Actually, if you care about performance, you want to do one thing: If you know how many elements are going to be added, detect if the container has `reserve()` and call it in advance. To detect `reserve()`, you can refer to [the first question I asked on SO and where it all started for me, and the answer for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882588). In fact I was working on this exact problem: How to fill a standard container with values.

Comment: Interesting (and very confusing!) link.  I will have to study that.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty I admit it might be a bit too advanced. I can edit the answer and add some example of how to use it, just leave another comment here in case you want that. It won't happen right now, though, because I'm going to sleep now :)

Comment: I'd appreciate that, when you have time, even if it's just a link or two.  Good night :)

Comment: @thirtythreeforty Good morning! I edited my answer as promised.

Answer (score 5):

Most often, people use traits.

Many boost libraries have solved this same problem, so you might be able to reuse existing traits.

A simple demonstration: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b560a19849ac3057)**

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

namespace traits
{
    template <typename Container, typename Enable = void>
        struct add_at_end;

    template <typename... TAs>
        struct add_at_end<std::vector<TAs...> > 
        {
            using Container = std::vector<TAs...>;

            template <typename... CtorArgs>
            static void apply(Container& container, CtorArgs&&... args) {
                container.emplace_back(std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...);
            }
        };

    template <typename... TAs>
        struct add_at_end<std::set<TAs...> > 
        {
            using Container = std::set<TAs...>;

            template <typename... CtorArgs>
            static void apply(Container& container, CtorArgs&&... args) {
                container.insert(container.end(), { std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...});
            }
        };

    template <typename... TAs>
        struct add_at_end<std::basic_string<TAs...> > 
        {
            using Container = std::basic_string<TAs...>;

            template <typename... CtorArgs>
            static void apply(Container& container, CtorArgs&&... args) {
                container.insert(container.end(), { std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...});
            }
        };
}

template <typename Container, typename... CtorArgs>
    void add_to(Container& container, CtorArgs&&... args) {
        traits::add_at_end<Container>::apply(container, std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...);
    }

int main()
{
    using X = std::pair<int, std::string>;

    std::vector<X> v;
    std::set<X>    s;
    std::wstring   wstr;
    std::string    str;

    add_to(v, 12, "hello");
    add_to(s, 42, "world");
    add_to(wstr, L'!');
    add_to(str, '?');
}
```

Basically, what you do, is have a free-standing utility function `add_to` that uses a trait class `traits::add_at_end` that can be specialized (in this case for any `vector<...>`, `set<...>`, or `basic_string<...>` template instances.

In practice, you would share the implementation for similar containers (e.g. `deque` and `vector`) by inheriting the common implementation.

Comment: I don't understand what that code does, although I think I understand the concept of traits.  Can you explain the code a bit?  What trait is the one that I'm looking for?

Comment: See the expanded answer with some explanations (now also showing a specialization for string types). See also live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b560a19849ac3057

Comment: Interesting.  (I also see `using` is a sort of `#DEFINE` for C++; didn't know that either!)  I'm going to study this; it may end up being necessary.  Does the STL provide any framework for setting this up?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty `using` is a c++11 template alias, it's more flexible than `typedef` (but `typedef` would be fine here). The standard library comes with a fair number of `type_traits` that you can use to compose your own traits from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

Answer (score 2):

`push_back` is supported by `std::string`, `std::vector`, and `std::list`.  With this, your class template is simply:

```
template<typename T>
class S {
  T built;
public:
  S() : built{} {}
  void add_to(typename T::value_type e) {
    built.push_back(e);
  }
  const T& get() {
    return built;
  }
};
```