# Calling different member functions on different classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, type-traits

I am trying to write a template function to insert an element into a container, such that it will use either `push_back()` or `insert()` depending on which is available.

[Edit:] It should also work on other (in-house) container-like types that define an `insert()` member function.

I've been looking into `<type_traits>` but so far couldn't come up with a non-clunky implementation.

Note: The compiler is VS2012 so not all C++11 features are available.

Comment: What do you do when both are available?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use

```
v.insert( v.end(), e );
```

as is will do both. It is equivalent to `push_back` for sequenced containers and just inserts the value in any associative container. If `MyContainer` does not support it, you should extend it. The above is the most portable way to insert/push back elements to all standard library containers.

---

I also asked a question some time ago on how to properly detect a member function of a container type, and I got a pretty good answer which you could adapt for `push_back` or `insert`. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882588). The reason I'm not really suggesting this here is that it is not needed (given the above) and I am not sure if VS2012 will compile it.

Comment: Can the v.end() hint adversely affect performance for some containers?

Comment: @AlexO In theory yes. If it is the *correct* hint, it could help in case of a `std::map` as you are already near the position in the tree where the element needs to be inserted. In case it's the wrong hint it *could* have a small additional overhead, but especially for `end()` being used as a "hint" there might be additional optimizations in an implementation. Or the hint is ignored altogether if it is `end()`. Personally I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have several internal container classes that expose an insert() member function bun not one with an iterator.  Also, the example you pointed to does not compile under VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function that you can implement for containers you want, like such:

```
template <class T>
void PushElement(std::vector<T> & v,const T & e)
{
    v.push_back(e);
}
template <class T>
void PushElement(MyContainer & v,const T & e)
{
    v.insert(e);
}
template <class C,class T>
void PushElement(C & ,const T & )
{
    assert(false && "Implementation missing");
    //error , the function was not specified for container C
}

template <class C>
class test
{
public:

    void add(const typename C::value_type & e)
    {
        PushElement(m_container,e);
        //for std::vector will use push_back
        //for MyContainer will use insert
        //for unknown container type you can throw assert

    }
    C m_container;
};
```

Razvan.