# C++ standard way to check if type has function with specific signature

Tags: c++, c++11

This question is related to: [Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)

Is this functionality implemented by C++11 standard or do I need to use custom implementation?

Comment: I am going to put forward the idea that you don't need this functionality. Test if the function is callable with a known set of arguments, and not its signature. In C++ for any function call there is an unbounded number of possible signatures that can accept that call. Why restrict yourself to one?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes In my case I need to check if a function with one parameter of specific type is present or not. I don't want any type conversion, functions with default parameters, functors or anything that can accept the call - but you are right, in general this check should be done if there is something that can accept the call or not.

Comment: @Vote to close for "too localized": how can a question about a std feature can be too localized?

Comment: You are asking a very specific question, how something is *done*. Maybe tell us what you want to *achieve* and somebody might have a good idea that does not involve such odd measures ;-)

Comment: use some SFINAE stuff. example for members: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector

Comment: @ArneMertz I ask if some functionality is present in the C++ standard or not. I already know how it's done(the answer is present in the other question) and how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this functionality implemented by C++11 standard

No, it's not. Implementing something like this generally had to be done using macros, to pass the function name in.

> do I need to use custom implementation?

Probably not. Such stuff is seldomly needed. There might be other solutions to your underlying problem.

Comment: I need to implement some mechanism to initialize my objects with default values depending on some traits. If the "Initialize" function is present in the traits class I have to call it on my object, else I will keep the values from constructor. This is done to avoid setting same values again and again from external editor.

Comment: I am not sure ifI understand completely what you want to achieve. Could you elaborate, maybe in a new question? Sounds like an interesting problem :-)

Comment: I added a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788931/mechanism-to-create-template-objects-in-c