# Mechanism to create "template" objects in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to be able to initialize objects with some default values, but to do this from external code(not embedded in the class itself). The objects are exposed to external editor and I don't want to set the same values again and again and change only some values that are different. As I have already template classes I want to do this from the "traits" class.

This is a simple samle of what I want to achieve:

```
template<typename Traits>
class Test
{
    public:
        Test()
        {
            //if Traits has Init init function call Traits::Init(this)
        }

    private:
        typename Traits::Type value;

    friend Traits;
};

struct TestTraits
{
    typedef std::string Type;
};

struct TestTraitsInit
{
    typedef int Type;

    static void Init(Test<TestTraitsInit>* obj)
    {
        obj->value = 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<TestTraits> obj1;
    Test<TestTraitsInit> obj2;
}
```

As you can see it makes sense to have `Init()` only in some cases. **Is it possible to check if class `Traits` has `Init()` function and call it only when it exists?**

I know that a very simple solution would be to have empty `Init()` functions, but I want a better solution:)

Comment: `TestTraitsInit` should not be able to access `object->value` it is private. Why don't you use inheritance and declare `Init()=0` and implement it empty when you do not need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create some class template `maybe_call_init` with a proper SFINAE-constrained specialization based on expression SFINAE:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct maybe_call_init
{
    static void maybe_call(Test<T>* obj) { }
};

template<typename T>
struct maybe_call_init<T,
    decltype(T::Init(std::declval<Test<T>*>()), void(0))>
{
    static void maybe_call(Test<T>* obj) { T::Init(obj); }
};
```

Given a trait `T`, `maybe_call_init<T>::maybe_call(obj)` will call `T::Init(obj)` if `T` defines such a function, and it will do nothing otherwise.

Then, you could use it in your original class template this way:

```
template<typename Traits>
class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        maybe_call_init<Traits>::maybe_call(this);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
private:
    typename Traits::Type value;
    friend Traits;
};
```

The above solution is a bit rudimental, and could be improved by hiding the `maybe_call_init` class template and its specialization in a `detail` namespace, providing a helper function to do the instantiation work. So given this machinery:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T, typename U, typename = void>
    struct maybe_call_init
    {
        static void maybe_call(U* obj) { }
    };

    template<typename T, typename U>
    struct maybe_call_init<T, U,
        decltype(T::Init(std::declval<U*>()), void(0))>
    {
        static void maybe_call(U* obj) { T::Init(obj); }
    };
}

template<template<typename> class T, typename U>
void maybe_call_init(T<U>* obj)
{
     detail::maybe_call_init<U, T<U>>::maybe_call(obj);
}
```

The constructor of your original `Test` class may now look like this:

```
template<typename Traits>
class Test
{
    public:
        Test()
        {
            maybe_call_init(this);
        //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }

    public:
        typename Traits::Type value;

    friend Traits;
};
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/ULTiC2).