# check if type can be explicitly converted

Tags: c++, c++11

How to determine (in the `<type_traits>` spirit) whether or not one type explicitly convertible into another type? For example, I want to check the presence of `F::explicit operator double const & () const;` for some `class`/`struct` `F`, but, at the same time, `F` should not been explicitly convertible to `float` or `long double` (something like `pred< double const & >::value && !pred< float >::value && !pred< long double >::value`).

Note, that `std::is_convertible< From, To >::value` checks "if *From* can be converted to *To* using **implicit conversion**". But I wish to determine whether there is the **explicit conversion** operator.

And, if it possible, the "how to determine, type *From* is convertible into a *namely* reference to type *To*?"?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but you can do a `dynamic_cast<TO &>(FROM &val)`, it will throw `std::bad_cast` if the conversion is not eligible.

Comment: @H2CO3 Assume, that question is about compile time issue.

Comment: As you want to probe for an explicit conversion operator, your task seems to boil down to [determining whether a class T has a member function with a given signature](http://stackoverflow.com/q/87372/1362568). There are
many answers there, including one of mine.

Comment: @MikeKinghan smells good.

Comment: @H2CO3 it won't compile.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Apparently, [`dynamic_cast` accepts references.](http://ideone.com/tVlKD2)

Comment: @H2CO3 Now try it with `long double`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to define your own:

```
template <class U, class T>
struct is_explicitly_convertible
{    
  enum {value = std::is_constructible<T, U>::value && !std::is_convertible<U, T>::value};
};
```

Comment: Using an `enum` for this is archaic. A `static constexpr bool` should be used instead, or better yet, inherit from `std::integral_constant<bool, (std::is_constructible<T, U>::value && !std::is_convertible<U, T>::value)>`.

Comment: @Pharap: Why not make that into an answer?

Answer (score 12):

Your test set is at an off-site link and has varied since your original
post, so I will copy verbatim the test-set I am talking about here:

```
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double, double >::value, "1");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double &, double >::value, "2");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double const, double >::value, "3");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double const &, double >::value, "4");

static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double, double const & >::value, "5");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double &, double const & >::value, "6");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double const, double const & >::value, "7");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double const &, double const & >::value, "8");

static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< double, double & >::value, "9"); // not a ref
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double &, double & >::value, "10");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< double const, double & >::value, "11");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< double const &, double & >::value, "12");

static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double, double const >::value, "13");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double &, double const >::value, "14");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double const, double const >::value, "15");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< double const &, double const >::value, "16");

static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< AA const &, A const & >::value, "=&1.a");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< CC const &, C const & >::value, "=&1.b");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< BB const &, B const & >::value, "=&1.c");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const &, A & >::value, "&1.a");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const &, C & >::value, "&1.b");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const &, B & >::value, "&1.c");

static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, A const & >::value, "=1.a");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, C const & >::value, "=1.b");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, B const & >::value, "=1.c");
//static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, A >::value, "=2.a"); // ???????????????
//static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, C >::value, "=2.b");
//static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, B >::value, "=2.c");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, A & >::value, "=3.a"); // good!
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, C & >::value, "=3.b"); //
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, B & >::value, "=3.c"); //
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, A && >::value, "=4.a"); // not interesting
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, C && >::value, "=4.b"); //
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, B && >::value, "=4.c"); //
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, B const & >::value, "=5.a");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, C const & >::value, "=5.b");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, A const & >::value, "=5.c");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, C const & >::value, "=6.a");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, A const & >::value, "=6.b");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, B const & >::value, "=6.c");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, B & >::value, "=7.a");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, C & >::value, "=7.b");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, A & >::value, "=7.c");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, C & >::value, "=8.a");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, A & >::value, "=8.b");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, B & >::value, "=8.c");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, B >::value, "=9.a"); // very subtle moment (see class AA above)
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA const, C >::value, "=9.b");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, A >::value == std::is_constructible< A, A && >::value, "=9.c"); // (see class BB above)
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB const, C >::value, "=10.a");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, A >::value, "=10.b");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC const, B >::value, "=10.c");

static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< AA, A & >::value, "~1.a");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< CC, C & >::value, "~1.b");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< BB, B & >::value, "~1.c");
//static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA, A >::value, "~2.a"); // ???????????????
//static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC, C >::value, "~2.b");
//static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB, B >::value, "~2.c");
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< AA, A const & >::value, "~3.a"); // convertible
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< CC, C const & >::value, "~3.b"); //
static_assert(is_explicitly_convertible< BB, B const & >::value, "~3.c"); //
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA, B const & >::value, "~4.a");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< AA, C const & >::value, "~4.b");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB, A const & >::value, "~4.c");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< BB, C const & >::value, "~5.a");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC, A const & >::value, "~5.b");
static_assert(!is_explicitly_convertible< CC, B const & >::value, "~5.c");

static_assert(std::is_convertible< double, double const & >::value, "5*");
static_assert(!std::is_convertible< double, double & >::value, "9*");
```

If you avail of gcc 4.7.2 (and maybe earlier, I haven't checked) then the C++11 
Standard Library solves the problem:

```
std::is_explicitly_convertible<From,To>
```

is defined in `<type_traits>`

However, you would then be availing of a [error](http://gcc.1065356.n5.nabble.com/Bug-libstdc-55053-New-std-is-explicitly-convertible-should-be-removed-td881522.html) in that version of the
C++11 Standard Library. This trait template shouldn't have been there, because
it was removed from the Standard pursuant to [N3047](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3047.html) (2010).

If you are on to gcc 4.8.1 (or maybe 4.8; I haven't checked) then this trait is
no longer in the library, and if you want it you must again roll your own.

But it would only be human to inspect the definition in gcc 4.7.2's `<type_traits>`
for a start, and doing that reveals that the GNU implementer considered the trait
to be nothing but the inverse of `std::is_constructible<To,From>`:

```
/// is_explicitly_convertible
template<typename _From, typename _To>
struct is_explicitly_convertible
: public is_constructible<_To, _From>
{ };
```

One may well think: *But of course.*

So why won't that do to be going on with? N3047 explains:

> The remaining question is, in which way the also affected `is_explicitly_convertible` trait should be repaired. The basic choices are:
>
> 1. Fix `is_explicitly_convertible` by returning to the current static_cast expression, no longer making `is_explicitly_convertible` dependent on `is_constructible`.
> 2. Remove `is_explicitly_convertible` from the standard.
>
> The first choice was considered, but it turned out that there exist quite different understandings of what "explicitly convertible" should actually mean. While some believe that `static_cast` correctly expresses this, others believed that the fixed `is_constructible` would provide a better meaning for `is_explicitly_convertible` as well. Therefore this paper recommends to remove the `is_explicitly_convertible` from the working draft. This should do no harm now, because nothing depends on that special definition yet.And if it turns out, that the trait would still be useful, it could be added in another revision of the standard.

There was no known bug in that definition, but there were opposed views as to whether the meaning of "explicitly convertible" that it codifies
is the right one:-

- D1) `From` is explicitly convertible to `To` =df `To` is constructible from `From`
- D2) `From` is explicitly convertible to `To` =df `From` can be statically cast to `To`

I will not argue to this controversy (I haven't even worked out what the difference is, myself) but will suggest that you just 
pay your money and take your choice.

If you favour D1) then you can simply take the definition of the trait from
the gcc 4.7.2 `<type_traits>`, as above.

If you favour D2, then you could plagiarize and adapt the definition of `std::is_convertible<From,To>`
from gcc 4.8.1 `<type_traits>`. This definition invokes 
internal auxiliary functions you would have to track down. The adaptation you
would want would be to change the SFINAE test for *`From` can be implicitly cast to
`To`* to a test for *`From` can be `static_cast` to `To`*; and that would mean
replacing:

```
  template<typename _From1, typename _To1>
    static decltype(__test_aux<_To1>(std::declval<_From1>()), __one())
__test(int);
```

with:

```
  template<typename _From1, typename _To1>
    static decltype(__test_aux<_To1>(static_cast<_To1>(std::declval<_From1>())), __one())
__test(int);
```

A cut-down version of this definition (ignoring such cases as
`From` being `void` and `To` being a function or array type) which would do
for the types that are tested in your `static_assert`s:

```
template<typename From, typename To>
struct is_explicitly_convertible
{
    template<typename T>
    static void f(T);

    template<typename F, typename T>
    static constexpr auto test(int) -> 
    decltype(f(static_cast<T>(std::declval<F>())),true) {
        return true;
    }

    template<typename F, typename T>
    static constexpr auto test(...) -> bool {
        return false;
    }

    static bool const value = test<From,To>(0);
};
```

Either the D1 definition or the cut-down D2 definition upholds all 63 of your `static_assert`s.
(I compiled with g++ 4.7.2 and 4.8.1, `-g;-O0;-Wall;-std=c++11`, and also with 
the `-std=gnu++1y` that you employed)

Your latest solution shows that you have made your own way to the D2 school, 
with a different style of implementation.

Of the two, until I find something wrong with it, I would prefer the D1 definition, as per gcc 4.7.2, merely because
it is much the simplest and in particular is a trivial derivative of 
`std::is_constructible`.

Comment: Both D1) and D2) approaches are completely equivalent on my test case on last __gcc__ (mingw-builds 4.8.1 rev0) with `-std=gnu++1y` option. So, finally, I choose D1), since it does not require me to write anything new.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering this now to add a C++20-style update with concepts, and to give a small note on what the standard library has in terms of [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) and [`std::convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to). From the best of my knowledge `std::is_convertible` checks for *implicit-convertability*, and `std::convertible_to` tests for both *implicit-convertability*, and *explicit-convertability*. We can steal the second part of the concept implementation of `std::convertible_to` to come up with something like:

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
concept explicitly_convertible_to = requires(T t) { static_cast<U>(t); };
```

If you don't have c++20 concepts, this will work as well:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class U, class = void>
struct is_explicitly_convertible_to_impl : std::false_type {};

template <class T, class U>
struct is_explicitly_convertible_to_impl<
    T, U, std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<U>(std::declval<T>()))>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <class T, class U>
struct is_explicitly_convertible_to
    : is_explicitly_convertible_to_impl<T, U> {};

template <class T, class U>
inline constexpr bool is_explicitly_convertible_to_v =
    is_explicitly_convertible_to<T, U>::value;
```

For anyone wondering why this may be necessary for more detailed meta-programing: there are indeed situations where one type is *explicitly*, but not *implicitly* convertible to another. Chiefly: given an `explicit` constructor, and a deleted assignment operator.