# How should I check whether a type is contextually convertible to bool?

Tags: c++, generics, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to write a concept that describes function objects that are not only [*invocable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) but, like [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), have an ["empty" state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool) that is [testable](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#5) via [contextual conversion to `bool`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#def:conversion,contextual_to_bool).

The [*boolean-testable*](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.booleantestable) exposition-only concept sounds like it might be appropriate but, since it is written in terms of [`convertible_to`](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.convertible#concept:convertible_to), requires that its argument be *implicitly* convertible to bool:

```
template<class T> concept BooleanTestable = std::convertible_to<T, bool>;
static_assert(BooleanTestable<void(*)()>); // ok
static_assert(BooleanTestable<std::function<void()>>); // fails :(
```

Is there something in the Standard `<concepts>` library that can help, or do I need to write a requires-expression myself, and if so, which form should I use? The definition of *contextually converted to `bool`* is [expressed](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#general-4) in the form of a declaration-statement (i.e., `bool t(E);`), but requires-expressions can only check expressions:

```
template<class T> concept ContextuallyConvertibleToBool = requires (T x) {
    bool(x); // constructor cast?
    static_cast<bool>(x); // or static_cast?
    x ? void() : void(); // or something a little stranger?
};
```

Considering subsumption, readability and maintenance, I'd prefer to use a form that has precedent.

Comment: Are you looking for [`is_explicitly_convertible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893992/check-if-type-can-be-explicitly-converted)?

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah yes, `is_constructible_v<bool, T>` should work, or maybe `constructible_from<bool, T>` - of course, the arguments are in the wrong order so I still need to write my own concept. If there's nothing better I'll go with that.

Answer (score 4):

The wording `contextually convertible` is applicable to expressions, not types.

> Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to a Boolean value. An expression E appearing in such a context is said to be contextually converted to bool and is well-formed if and only if the declaration bool t(E); is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t ([dcl.init]).

That's why the exact concept definition depends on your context and what *exactly* you want to constraint.

Below is an example of a type that passes `constructible_from<bool, T>` test, but fails to compile:

```
struct S {
    constexpr explicit operator bool() && noexcept {
        return false;
    }
};

void F() {
    S s;
    static_assert(std::constructible_from<bool, S>);
    if (s) {

    }
}
```

What we probably want above is `std::constructible_from<bool, S&>`. But this also affects a name of your concept, because you are now checking not the fact that your type is contextually convertible, but if your type can be used in a particular context. For example:

```
struct S1 {
    constexpr explicit operator bool() && noexcept {
        return false;
    }
};

struct S2 {
    constexpr explicit operator bool() noexcept {
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename T>
concept CanBeUsedWithF = std::constructible_from<bool, T&>;

template <CanBeUsedWithF T>
void F() {
    T s;
    if (s) {

    }
}

F<S1>();  // constraints not satisfied
F<S2>();
```

Comment: What you probably want is `static_assert(std::constructible_from<bool, decltype((s))>);` to take all guesswork regarding types out of the equation. `std::constructible_from<bool, const std::remove_reference_t<S>&>` is certainly not the correct test since `s` is not actually `const` (and though harmless in this case, `std::remove_reference_t<S>` is superfluous).

Comment: It was done for illustration purposes, but I agree that in this particular context `s` is an non-const lvalue, I'll change the example to avoid confusion.