# Can I detect if a member function exists and is accessible to a friend in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, templates, c++11, sfinae

I am trying to take the ideas from [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) and apply them, but I am running into some trouble. I have the following defined:

```
#define HAS_MEM_FUNC(func, name)                                        \
    template<typename T, typename Sign>                                 \
    struct name {\
        typedef char yes[1];                                            \
        typedef char no[2];                                            \
        template <typename U, U> struct type_check;                     \
        template <typename _1> static yes &chk(type_check<Sign, &_1::func> *); \
        template <typename   > static no  &chk(...);                    \
        static bool const value = sizeof(chk<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);     \
    }

// Creates a member function detector and two overloads of a message handler
// registration function, one that registers a member function of a specific name
// if it exists and another that does nothing if that member function doesn't exist.

#define DEFINE_REGISTER_FUNC(msgid, msgtype, handlername) \
    HAS_MEM_FUNC(handlername, has_##handlername);\
    template <typename T>\
    static void register_##handlername(\
        T* pWnd, \
        typename std::enable_if<has_##handlername<T, void(T::*)(msgtype&)>::value, T>::type* t = nullptr) \
    {\
        (void) t;\
        pWnd->setMessageHandler(\
            msgid,\
            Handler<msgtype>(std::bind(&T::handlername, pWnd, std::placeholders::_1)));\
    }\
    \
    template <typename T> \
    static void register_##handlername(\
        T* pWnd, \
        typename std::enable_if<!has_##handlername<T, void(T::*)(msgtype&)>::value, T>::type* t = nullptr) \
    {\
        (void)pWnd;\
        (void)t;\
    }
```

I also have a class defined like this:

```
template <typename T>
class RegisterHandlers
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void registerHandlers(T* pWnd)
    {
        register_onCreate(pWnd);
        register_onPaint(pWnd);
    }

private:
    DEFINE_REGISTER_FUNC(WM_CREATE, CreateMessage, onCreate);
    DEFINE_REGISTER_FUNC(WM_PAINT, PaintMessage, onPaint);
};
```

The idea is that if the class `T` has a member function `onCreate(CreateMessage&)`, it will automatically be registered as the handler for `WM_CREATE`. If it has no such method, then the do-nothing overload of `register_onCreate` will be called and the compiler will be happy. Same for the onPaint handler (I included that mostly to illustrate that the SFINAE *does* work).

This works fine if I have a class like this:

```
class MainWnd
{
public:
    friend class RegisterHandlers<MainWnd>;

    MainWnd()
    {
        RegisterHandlers<MainWnd>::registerHandlers(this);
    }

protected:
    void onCreate(CreateMessage&) { /* do some stuff */ }
};
```

However, the moment I add this:

```
class SubWnd : public MainWnd
{
public:
    friend class RegisterHandlers<SubWnd>;

    SubWnd()
    {
        RegisterHandlers<SubWnd>::registerHandlers(this);
    }

protected:
    void onPaint(PaintMessage&) { /* do some stuff */ }
};
```

I get an error that `MainWnd::onCreate` is inaccessible (cannot access protected member). I broke down the macros to help find where the problem is actually occurring, and it seems to be in the `HAS_MEM_FUNC` macro, probably at this line:

```
template <typename _1> static yes &chk(type_check<Sign, &_1::func> *);
```

So, I have two questions really:

1. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do without making the event handlers public?
2. Is it also possible to avoid re-registering event handlers if the base class already did it? Phrased another way, is there a way to tell if the function was declared in the base class or if it originated in the derived class?

In case it's relevant, I am trying to do this on the Visual Studio 2013 Preview compiler. The motivation for this question is that I am experimenting with C++11 features and Windows API wrappers, and I am trying to see if there are better solutions than large vtables and message map macros for routing messages to an appropriate handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obstacle here is this:

Class `SubWnd`, derived from `MinWnd`, declares friendship:

```
friend class RegisterHandlers<SubWnd>;
```

so that `RegisterHandlers<SubWnd>::registerHandlers(this)` can do the registering of its
own protected handler `onPaint` and also - redundantly - of the
protected handler `onCreate` that it inherits from `MainWnd`. The
latter registration is redundant because the base
class `MainWnd`'s constructor will already have registered `onCreate`.
`RegisterHandlers<T>::registerHandlers(WinType *)`  is always going to "register" 
all the handlers that any window might have, doing a no-op if `WinType` 
doesn't actually have a given handler and repeating the registration if it 
has already been done by a base class constructor.

But to register `onCreate`, redundantly or not, which is a protected member
of `MainWnd`, `RegisterHandlers<SubWnd>` needs to be a friend of `MainWnd`.
And it isn't: it is only a friend of `SubWnd`.

You cannnot get rid of the template parameterization of `RegisterHandlers<T>`
by window-type `T` because you depend on that template parameter for your
SFINAE method-introspecting

But this SFINAE method-introspecting, I have to say,
is a futile palaver in the present case. Every one of your window-class constructors 
still has to do something to get its own handlers registered. The way that you want it 
to go about this is by delegating the task to `RegisterHandlers<T>::registerHandlers(WinType *)`, which will:

- Attempt to register all handlers any window could have,
- Doing nothing whenever `WinType` doesn't have the handler,
- Redundantly re-registering the handler when `WinType`'s base class constructor has already registered it, and
- Non-redundantly and successfully registering the specific handlers of `WinType`.

The only part of all this that each window type actually, but unavoidably, needs to do is the last. So
to your two questions:

> 1. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do without making the event handlers public?

Yes. Just have each window-type register its own handlers.

> 2. Is it also possible to avoid re-registering event handlers if the base class already did it?

Yes. Same answer.

I appreciate that you are merely experimenting, but this experiment is not promising.

You attached a third question to question 2:

> Is there a way to tell if the function was declared in the base class or if it originated in the derived class

Yes. If you consult again [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87846/1362568),
and then also consult [my answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707822/1362568)
just below, you will see that the first solution detects a member function `T::mf`
when `mf` is defined in `T` but not when `mf` is inherited by `T`, whereas my
solution detects `mf` in either case. Thus you can SFINAE-probe for `T::mf` by
both methods and will know that `mf` is inherited if the first method does not
detect it and the second method does.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If this can be made to work, it wouldn't be entirely futile, because it could get rid of tons of redundant boilerplate. As long as something called `registerHandlers` in its ctor new event handlers could be added without having to go back and change the ctor. The redundant re-registration is a sticking point to me, because it means higher overhead than I'd like, but at the end of the day it doesn't affect correctness. I will look at those answers and see what they tell me :)

Comment: OK, so far I have been able to eliminate the duplicate registrations using the multi-checking method you suggested. But it looks like the only way to avoid making the event handlers public would be to have each class redefine the `register_xx` functions itself, which would defeat the purpose of reducing boilerplate. It seems like if I decide to pursue this route I would have to accept public event handlers as a trade-off.