# How to use `is_member_function_pointer` to include/exclude member function calls in algorithms?

Tags: c++, stl, template-meta-programming

I am trying to use [is_member_function_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) within an algorithm, to either call a specific member function of a type (if it exists), or do nothing at all:

```
template< class T >
struct is_member_function_pointer;
```

> Checks whether T is a non-static member function pointer. Provides the member constant value which is equal to true, if T is a non-static member function pointer type. Otherwise, value is equal to false.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    void boo() const { std::cout << "boo." << std::endl; } 
};

struct B {};

template<bool> struct booable; 

template<>
struct booable<true> {

    template<typename Type>
    static void booIt(Type const & t)
    {
        t.boo(); 
    }
};

template<>
struct booable<false> {

    template<typename Type>
    static void booIt(Type const & t)
    {
        std::cout << "booing a non-booable type" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename Type>
void alg(Type const& t)
{
    booable<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&Type::boo)>::value>::booIt(t); 
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    A a;  
    B b; 

    alg(a); 
    alg(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Struct `A` is *booable* and `B` is not. Within the algorithm `alg`, `is_member_function_pointer` boolean value is set to `false` or `true` depending on the fact if `Type` implements a member function `boo`. This boolean value is then used to specialize the `booable` struct, that implements `booIt` static member function, whose sole purpose is to either call `boo` on a booable object, or *do nothing and inform the user*.

However, compiling this (saved im `main.cpp`), results in a following compile-time error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void alg(const Type&) [with Type = B]’:
main.cpp:46:10:   required from here
main.cpp:37:54: error: ‘boo’ is not a member of ‘B’
booable<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&Type::boo)>::value>::booIt(t);
```

Which makes me wonder: isn't reporting this *as a useable boolean value and not a compile-time error* the point of this trait structure? This is the same error I would get by simply doing

```
B b; 
b.boo();
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: `is_member_function_pointer` classifies a *type,* i.e. it can be used to tell a `T(*)()` from a `T (C::*)()`. For introspection, you need heavier guns - something like what [Boost.TTI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_member_function.html) provides.

Comment: @Angew: thanks for the Boost tip, but I don't understand what you mean by type classification. `is_member_function_pointer` provides a static boolean variable `value`, can't i just use that like I did above?

Comment: Because the expression `&Type::boo` requires `Type` to have a `boo` member. You could use `is_member_function_pointer` to determine whether this `boo` is a member function or a data member. But it has to exist. The TTI library I linked to uses SFINAE to perform some level of compile-time introspection (actually determining *whether* a nested `boo` exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't reporting this as a useable boolean value and not a compile-time error the point of this trait structure?

Yes, but in order to test some member of a class, that member  needs to exist.

You get the error because `B` doesn't have `boo` and instantiating `alg` results in `decltype(&B::boo)`. You wouldn't expect `decltype(&int::foo)` to compile, would you?

What you need is a trait that check for *existense* of a member. See

- [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)
- [Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)

for examples.

You can use the result of the check to specialize the template that does further test.

EDIT:

Here's a simple way to do check for `boo` using expression SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto is_booable(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().boo(), bool())
{
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_booable(...)
{
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
booable< is_booable<Type>(0) >::booIt(t);
```

And [**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5edba3a6cd6f7ff4).

Comment: ah! :D ok, now I see.