# Template instantiation does not "do inheritance"

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The title is quoted from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707822/862351). It is discussing using SFINAE to detect the existence of a member function with the given signature and points out a failing of the method in the accepted answer when dealing with inherited member functions. In particular, the explanation given is as follows

> If you are not already wise to this gotcha, then a look at of the definition of `std::shared_ptr<T>` in the header  will shed light. In that implementation, `std::shared_ptr<T>` is derived from a base class from which it inherits `operator*() const`. So the template instantiation `SFINAE<U, &U::operator*>` that constitutes "finding" the operator for `U = std::shared_ptr<T>` will not happen, because `std::shared_ptr<T>` has no `operator*()` in its own right and template instantiation does not "do inheritance".
>
> This snag does not affect the well-known SFINAE approach, using "The sizeof() Trick", for detecting merely whether T has some member function mf (see e.g. this answer and comments).

Using the terminology from the answer, what is the difference between using `T::mf` as a template argument to instantiate a type vs having the compiler determine it through a template function argument deduction? What does "template instantiation does not do inheritance" mean? And lastly, why doesn't this affect simply checking for existence of a member, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/862351)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimized example:

```
struct A {
    void a() const;
};

struct B : A {};

template<typename U, void (U::*)() const> struct SFINAE {};
template<typename U> void Test(SFINAE<U, &U::a>*) { }

int main(void)
{
    Test<B>(0); // doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80cb9f00c36f3c30).

The problem is that when `B::a` is inherited from `A`, the type of `&B::a` is actually "pointer to member of `A`" - and, while normally a pointer-to-member-of-base can be implicitly converted to pointer-to-member-of-derived, this conversion doesn't apply for non-type template arguments, per §14.3.2 [temp.arg.nontype]/p5:

> The following conversions are performed on each expression used as a
>   non-type *template-argument*. If a non-type template-argument cannot
>   be converted to the type of the corresponding *template-parameter*
>   then the program is ill-formed.
>
> - [...]
> - For a non-type *template-parameter* of type pointer to member function,
>     if the template-argument is of type `std::nullptr_t`, the
>     null member pointer conversion (4.11) is applied; otherwise, no
>     conversions apply. If the *template-argument* represents a set of
>     overloaded member functions, the matching member function is selected
>     from the set (13.4).