# Using `void_t` to check if a class has a method with a specific signature

Tags: c++, templates, void, template-meta-programming, c++14

At the moment, I'm [using this method to check if a class has a method with a specific signature.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824239/598696)

After attending [Walter E. Brown's metaprogramming CppCon2014 talk](http://cppcon2014.sched.org/speaker/walter_e_brown#.VD1S8XVsYWM), I started wondering if `void_t` could be used in this particular situation to make the code cleaner and more readable.

However I'm having trouble thinking in terms of  `void_t` - so far I understand that `void_t` can help me determine at compile-time whether or not an expression is valid.

Example:

```
template< class, class = void >
struct has_type_data_member : false_type { };

template< class T >
struct has_type_data_member<T, void_t<decltype(T::data)>> : true_type { };
```

If `decltype(T::type)` is a valid expression, `has_type_data_member<T>` will be a true compile-time constant. Therefore, we are sure that `T` has a member field called `data`.

I want to use the same approach to check if a type `T` has a method with a particular name and a particular signature.

Let's say I want to check if `T` has a method called `getCount()` that returns `int`. This is what I expected to work [((Ideone.com link))](http://ideone.com/IaUORc):

```
template< class, class = void >
struct hasGetCount : false_type { };

template< class T >
struct hasGetCount<T, VoidT<decltype(T::getCount)>> 
: std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().getCount()), int>::type { };
```

Unfortunately, the `static_assert` tests do not pass.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to use `void_t` in this situation?

**Bonus questions:**

- How can I also check if the method signature is equal to a signature the user passes as in the original implementation?
- I can use macros to define these kind of helper structs like this:

  ```
   DEFINE_METHOD_CHECKER(hasGetCount, getCount);
   // ...
   static_assert(hasGetCount<ClassWithGetCount>::value == true, "");
  ```

  Is it possible to avoid having to define a `struct` first then check the struct's value?         I mean, is it possible to use a macro to write something like this? Example:

  ```
   static_assert(CHECK_METHOD(ClassWithGetCount, getCount)::value == true, "");
  ```

Comment: A *id-expression* naming a nonstatic member function cannot be used in a `decltype`.

Comment: @T.C.: I see - is there an alternative way to produce a valid/invalid expression depending on whether a type has/hasn't got a method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, an *id-expression* naming a nonstatic member function can't be used as an unevaluated operand (such as the operand of `decltype`). Moreover, you should check for whether the entire function call expression is well formed, not just whether there is a member called `getCount`:

```
template< class, class = void >
struct hasGetCount : false_type { };

template< class T >
struct hasGetCount<T, VoidT<decltype(std::declval<T>().getCount())>> 
: std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().getCount()), int>::type { };
```

(Use `declval<T&>` if you want to check that `getCount()` can be called on an lvalue.)

If you just check for the existence of a `getCount` member, then you get a hard error if a member with that name exists but isn't callable (e.g., a data member).

Although at this point you might as well consider just using something like

```
template< class T >
struct hasGetCount<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().getCount()), int>::value>> : std::true_type { };
```

instead of writing the `decltype` twice.

Comment: `declval<T>` produces an xvalue, so if you want to check if `getCount()` can be called on an lvalue, use `declval<T&>` (relevant since ref-qualifiers).

Comment: SFINAE is a result of the rules for class template specialization and overload resolution involving function templates. `enable_if` is neither a necessary nor sufficient ingredient for it. Should you want to rewrite the test in function template form, something like `template<typename T> typename std::is_same<int, decltype( std::declval<T&>().getCount() )>::type test(int);` is a good start and doesn’t use `enable_if`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `void_t` to easily verify that the return type of `getCount` is convertible to `int`:

```
template< class, class = void >
struct hasGetCount : false_type { };

template< class T >
struct hasGetCount<T,
  VoidT<
    decltype(std::declval<int&>() = std::declval<T>().getCount())
  >> : std::true_type {};
```

(**[Ideone live code](http://ideone.com/Tt5yvE)**)

Hopefully, by the time C++17 comes out, we'll be able to do this more easily with [Concepts Lite](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/cplusplus/concepts-ts/blob/n4205/concepts.html):

```
template <typename T>
concept bool hasGetCount = requires (T t) {
  { t.getCount() } -> int;
};
```

Comment: Though this check only is correct for non-class types on the lhs of `=`, otherwise, you're checking assignability. Similarly, it won't work for function types and arrays (directly) as far as I see.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to check for the parameters to the function and its return type, similar to what [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923854/casey) suggested

```
template<typename... > struct Voider { using Type = void; };
template<typename... TArgs> using void_t = typename Voider<TArgs...>::Type;

template<class, typename, class = void>
struct hasGetCount : false_type { };

template< class T,  typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct hasGetCount<T, Ret(Args...), 
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<Ret&>() 
        = std::declval<T>().getCount(std::declval<Args>()...))
          >> : std::is_same<
               decltype(std::declval<T().getCount(std::declval<Args>()...)), 
               Ret>::type {};
```

Usage:

```
class A {
public:
    int member;
    int getCount() {return 0;}
};
static_assert( hasGetCount<A, int(void)>::value , "A" );
```