# Fill a vector with pointers to partially specialized function members automatically

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, function-signature

I am working on a pipeline-like design pattern. One of my design goals is to enable dynamic linking of pipeline segments by providing pointers to function members of a certain data class.

Each of the data classes has a set of function members (representing the data class output ports) indexed using an integer template argument. These functions deduce the return type dynamically using keyword `auto`, but all accept the same integer argument `c_Idx`, i.e. `template <int N> auto getOutput(int c_Idx) const`. The functionality associated with each function `getOutput` is defined (by the user) in a set of partially specialised structures `getOutputImpl`. Thus, each data class can have from 1 up to some fixed number `K` of output data ports.

In order to allow for dynamic linking between the pipeline segments in a generic manner they can be stored in a container of the type `std::vector<boost::any>`. However, I need to be able to fill this vector with pointers to the function member templates automatically.

An example of a manual implementation is shown below

```
template<class TLeafType>
class AlgorithmOutput
{

protected:

    std::vector<boost::any> OutputPorts;

public:

    AlgorithmOutput()
        {

            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // This procedure needs to be automated //
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            std::function<std::unique_ptr<double>(int)> pOutFun1 = std::bind(
                std::mem_fn(
                    true ? &AlgorithmOutput<TLeafType>::getOutput<0> : nullptr
                    ),
                this,
                std::placeholders::_1
                );
            OutputPorts.push_back(pOutFun1);

            std::function<std::unique_ptr<int>(int)> pOutFun2 = std::bind(
                std::mem_fn(
                    true ? &AlgorithmOutput<TLeafType>::getOutput<1> : nullptr
                    ),
                this,
                std::placeholders::_1
                );
            OutputPorts.push_back(pOutFun2);

        }

    virtual ~AlgorithmOutput() {}

protected:

    TLeafType* asLeaf(void)
        {
            return static_cast<TLeafType*>(this);
        }

    TLeafType const* asLeaf(void) const
        {
            return static_cast<TLeafType const*>(this);
        }

public:

    template <int N>
    auto getOutput(int c_Idx) const
        {
            return asLeaf() -> getOutput<N>(c_Idx);
        }

    boost::any getOutputPort(int PortIdx)
        {
            return OutputPorts[PortIdx];
        }

};

class PipeOutputClass: public AlgorithmOutput<PipeOutputClass>
{

public:

    template <int N>
    auto getOutput(int c_Idx) const
        {
            return getOutputImpl<N>::apply(this, c_Idx);
        }

    template<int N, typename S> friend struct getOutputImpl;

    template<int N, typename = void>
    struct getOutputImpl
    {
        static auto apply(
            PipeOutputClass const* p_Self,
            int c_Idx
            )
            { throw std::runtime_error("Wrong template argument."); }
    };

    template <typename S>
    struct getOutputImpl<0, S>
    {
        static std::unique_ptr<double> apply(
            PipeOutputClass const* p_Self,
            int c_Idx
            )
            {
                std::unique_ptr<double> mydouble(new double(10));
                return mydouble;
            }
    };

    template <typename S>
    struct getOutputImpl<1, S>
    {
        static std::unique_ptr<int > apply(
            PipeOutputClass const* p_Self,
            int c_Idx
            )
            {
                std::unique_ptr<int > myint(new int(3));
                return myint;
            }
    };

};
```

The problem with the example above is that I define the member function pointers `pOutFunX` manually, whereas I would like to automate this procedure.

Please note that I am not considering design solutions which differ significantly from the design specified above.

---

Here I present some thoughts on some of the possible approaches for solving this problem. I developed a plan for a solution that I am currently considering, which may be of use if you attempt to answer this question:

1. Obtain the number of the user defined partially specialised structures named `getOutputImpl`.
2. For each such structure determine the output type of its member named `apply`.
3. Set up a (recursive) meta-template procedure that creates pointers to functions with the relevant signature and adds them to the `OutputPort` vector.

I would assume that the steps 1-3 above will all have to be done at compile time. I am not concerned about the aesthetics of the solution, if it does not require any intervention from the user designing the data output classes. However, I would prefer not to use custom compiler macros.

This post shows how one can [infer a member function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature), which may be useful.

Comment: What is the purpose of this conditional-expression? `true ? &AlgorithmOutput<TLeafType>::getOutput<0> : nullptr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using AO=AlgorithmOutput;
template<size_t N>
using R=decltype(std::declval<AO*>()->getOutput<N>(0));
template<size_t... Is>
std::vector< boost::any > make_vec( std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
  return {
    boost::any(
      std::function< R<Is>(int) >{
        [this](int x){return this->getOutput<N>(x);}
      }
    )...
  };
}
```

Uses a C++14 type, but one easy to write.  Pass it `std::make_index_sequence<Count>{}` and it will return a vector populated with any wrapping functions wrapping lambdas which call your `apply`.

Your design looks like a mess of static dispatch, dynamic dispatch, type erasure and inefficient pointer semantics, but I assume (charitbly) this is just a simplification of a much more complex problem, and the design is warrented.

However, your runtime check that a static argument is incorrect should not stand.  Do not check for compile time errors at runtime.

```
static auto apply( PipeOutputClass const* p_Self, int c_Idx ) { throw std::runtime_error("Wrong template argument."); }
```

this seems pointless: make it fail to compile, not compile and throw.

Answer (score 2):

We know that for each template argument for which `getOutput` is not defined, its return type is `void`. So we can determine `K` as follows:

```
template <int K>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<decltype(getOutput<K>(0))>{}, int> getK() {
    return K-1;
}
template <int K>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<decltype(getOutput<K>(0))>{}, int> getK() {
    return getK<K+1>();
}
```

Also, you can "automate" your `push_back`s as follows:

```
     AlgorithmOutput() : AlgorithmOutput(std::make_index_sequence<getK<0>()>()) {}

private:


     template <std::size_t... indices>
     AlgorithmOutput( std::integer_sequence<indices...> )
     {
         (void)std::initializer_list<int> {
             (OutputPorts.push_back([this] (int i) {return getOutput<indices>(i);}, 0)...
         };
     }
```

(All code untested, merely sketches!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did not work 'out of the box'. However, I managed to get it working after making some amendments - see my answer. Since I have only just started learning variadic templates/C++11/14, I do believe that the code may be very far from optimal. Thus, I will appreciate any comments on the code in my answer.