# C++ CRTP based dataflow output class design simplification

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, crtp, dataflow

---

**Background information**

I am working on a dataflow-like design pattern. The classes presented below are meant to represent the output data dispatch mechanism. `level1` is a CRTP base class. `getOutput<N>` in `level1` is the function that can be used for getting the output data from an instance of a derived class. Depending on the template parameter `N` it calls one of the user defined methods `getOutputImpl`. These methods are meant to be provided in a (CRTP-style) derived class. Each of the methods `getOutputImpl` defines an output port associated with the user defined derived class. The input type of the method `getOutputImpl` is defined by design. The output types of the methods `getOutputImpl` can vary. However, by design, the output type must have a structure `std::unique_ptr<TOutputType>`, where TOutputType can be any class. More background information can be found here: [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843398/c-partial-template-specialization-design-simplification).

---

**Question**

To allow for automatic recognition of the number of the user defined ports (i.e. methods `getOutputImpl`) a method `getOutputPortsNumber(void)` is provided in the base `level1` class. This method is based around the idea that the return type of all user defined methods `getOutputImpl` is `std::unique_ptr<TOutputType>`. Thus, one can define an additional `getOutputImpl` method in the base class that does not have this return type (e.g. it has a `void` return type: `void getOutputImpl(...)`).

The methodology described above works if the `void getOutputImpl(...)` is defined within the user-defined derived class (`DataflowOutputClass` in this example) along with other user-defined `std::unique_ptr<TOutputType> getOutputImpl(...)` methods. However, when the additional `void getOutputImpl(...)` method is moved to the base `level1` class, I get a compilation error: `no matching function for call to 'DataflowOutputClass<int>::getOutputImpl(PortIdxType<2ul>, const PolyIndex&) const`.

---

**Code**

```
typedef size_t Index;
typedef unsigned long Natural;
typedef std::vector<Index> PolyIndex;
typedef const PolyIndex& crPolyIndex;
template<Index N> struct PortIdxType{};

template<typename TLeafType>
class level1
{

public:

    TLeafType* asLeaf(void)
        {return static_cast<TLeafType*>(this);}

    TLeafType const* asLeaf(void) const
        {return static_cast<TLeafType const*>(this);}

    template <Index N>
    auto getOutput(crPolyIndex c_Idx) const
        {return asLeaf() -> getOutputImpl(PortIdxType<N>{}, c_Idx);}

    static constexpr Natural getOutputPortsNumber(void)
        {return getOutputPortsNumberImpl<0>();}

    template<Index N>
    static constexpr std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_void<
            decltype(
                std::declval<TLeafType*>() ->
                getOutput<N>(PolyIndex({}))
                )
        >::value,
            Index
            > getOutputPortsNumberImpl(void)
        {return N;}

    template<Index N>
    static constexpr std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_void<
            decltype(
                std::declval<TLeafType*>() ->
                getOutput<N>(PolyIndex({}))
                )
        >::value,
            Index
            > getOutputPortsNumberImpl(void)
        {return getOutputPortsNumberImpl<N + 1>();}

    template<Index N>
    void getOutputImpl(
        PortIdxType<N>, crPolyIndex c_Idx
        ) const
        {throw std::runtime_error("Wrong template argument.");}


};

template<typename T>
class DataflowOutputClass:
    public level1<DataflowOutputClass<T>>
{
public:

    // if void getOutputImpl(...) const is moved here from level1,
    // then the code compiles and works correctly.

    //overload for when N = 0
    std::unique_ptr<double> getOutputImpl(
        PortIdxType<0>, crPolyIndex c_Idx
        ) const
    {
        std::unique_ptr<double> mydouble(new double(10));
        return mydouble;
    }

    //overload for when N = 1
    std::unique_ptr<int> getOutputImpl(
        PortIdxType<1>, crPolyIndex c_Idx
        ) const
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int> myint(new int(3));
        return myint;
    }

};


int main()
{
    DataflowOutputClass<int> a;
    std::cout << a.getOutputPortsNumber() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::declval<TLeafType*>() -> getOutput<N>` cannot be used in a return type, since `TLeafType` is still incomplete in that context (according to clang). Possibly, you could use another template type parameter defaulted to `TLeafType` instead.

Comment: I think you also need a `template` before mentioning the member function `getOutput` after the `->`.

Comment: [Fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ba0fcc9157c816). The last missing part was a using-declaration in the derived class, since it hides its base classes `getOutputImpl` overloads.

Comment: @dyp Thank you. It does solve the problem well. However, it is not a perfect solution. I was hoping to find a way to allow users to completely avoid mentioning (in any form) the additional `getOutputImpl` method with the `void` return type. Also, I am not sure if I need to have the `template` keyword before calling the `getOutput` method. The code works without the keyword if compiled with gcc 4.9.1. It would be interesting to understand why you would normally need or not need the keyword.

Comment: With respect to the keyword `template`: As far as I can see, it is required by [temp.names]p4. Consider `int getOutput;` and `bool operator> (bool, PolyIndex)`, then the expression `declval<T*>() -> getOutput<N>(PolyIndex({}))` could be parsed as `((declval<T*>()->getOutput) < N) > PolyIndex{}`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32413076fe4e619b)

Comment: The other issue can be solved by using a different technique to detect the `getOutputImpl` in the derived class: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12004916ccab59e8 But that's probably more an answer to your previous question.

Comment: @dyp Thank you. The code you provided in your last comment answers both questions. I will accept it if you post it as an answer to this or previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original code, I identified three issues:

1. `std::declval<TLeafType*>() -> getOutput` tries to look up a name in an incomplete class.
2. `std::declval<TLeafType*>() -> getOutput<N>` does not name a function template `getOutput`.
3. The `getOutputImpl` declarations in the derived class hide any member functions with the same name of the base class.

---

## 1 Looking up a name in an incomplete class

The expression `std::declval<TLeafType*>() -> getOutput` is used in the return type of `DataflowOutputClass::getOutputPortsNumberImpl`.

Instantiating a class template leads to the instantiation of the declarations of all member functions. When you derive with CRTP via `level1<DataflowOutputClass<T>>` in the `DataflowOutputClass` class, the compiler needs to instantiate `level1<..>` before instantiating the derived class. Therefore, during the instantiation of `level1<DataflowOutputClass<T>>`, the `DataflowOutputClass<T>` class is still incomplete.

A workaround is to postpone the determination of the return type of `DataflowOutputClass::getOutputPortsNumberImpl` by making it dependent on a template parameter of the function template:

```
template<Index N, typename T = TLeafType>
static constexpr std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_void<
        decltype(
            std::declval<T*>() ->
            getOutput<N>(PolyIndex({}))
            )
    >::value,
        Index
        > getOutputPortsNumberImpl(void)
    {return N;}
```

Now, the return type is dependent on a template-parameter *of the function template*. This return type can only be resolved when the *function* is instantiated. The function is instantiated implicitly via the usage of `getOutputPortsNumber` in `main`, where the derived class is already complete.

Note that it is not necessary to look up the name `getOutput` in the scope of the derived class, you can as well default `T = level1`. We would not look up a name in the derived class if we used:

```
template<Index N, typename T = TLeafType>
static constexpr std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_void<
        decltype(
            getOutput<N>(PolyIndex({}))
            )
    >::value,
        Index
        > getOutputPortsNumberImpl(void)
    {return N;}
```

However, to determine the return type of this `getOutputPortsNumberImpl`, instantiating the definition of `getOutput` is necessary, because `getOutput` uses return type deduction. Its definition will suffer from a similar problem as the original code: it tries to look up a name in an incomplete type.

Fixing the issue with return type deduction by making the return type of the calling function template dependent on a function template parameter seems like a poor fix to me, but the whole technique can be replaced by something simpler, see below.

---

## 2 `declval<TLeafType*> -> getOutput<N>` does not name a function template

In #1, we have already replaced this with `std::declval<T*>() -> getOutput<N>(PolyIndex({}))`, but the issue is the same. Consider:

```
bool operator> (bool, PolyIndex);

// class template level1

struct derived
{
    int getOutput;
};
```

With this setup, an expression like `declval<T*>() -> getOutput<N>(PolyIndex({}))` can be parsed as:

```
(
  (declval<T*>()->getOutput)  <  N
)
>
(
  PolyIndex({})
)
```

That is, `(x < N) > PolyIndex{}`.

To allow the compiler to understand that `getOutput` is a template, use the `template` keyword:

```
std::declval<T*>() -> template getOutput<N>(PolyIndex{})
```

(The additional `()` to initialize `PolyIndex` are unnecesary.)

---

## 3 Derived class member functions hide base class member functions

In general, any member in a derived class hides members of the same name of the base classes. To overload a member function in a derived class with member functions in a base class, you can use a *using-declaration* to "inject" the name of the base member into the derived class:

```
template<typename T>
class DataflowOutputClass:
    public level1<DataflowOutputClass<T>>
{
public:

    using level1<DataflowOutputClass<T>>::getOutputImpl;

    //overload for when N = 0
    std::unique_ptr<double> getOutputImpl(
        PortIdxType<0>, crPolyIndex c_Idx
        ) const;

    // ...
};
```

---

## 4 A solution that does not require a using-declaration

Currently, a using-declaration is required since the OP's metaprogramming must produce a valid return type for the expression `getOutput<N>(PolyIndex({}))`. The current approach differentiates `void` from non-`void` return types. Instead, we can simply detect if the expression `getOutput<N>(PolyIndex{})` is well-formed. For this, I'll use Walter E. Brown's `void_t` technique:

```
template<typename T>
struct voider { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
using void_if_well_formed = typename voider<T>::type;
```

We will use this as follows:

```
void_if_well_formed< decltype(expression) >
```

will yield the type `void` if the expression is well-formed. Otherwise, if the expression is ill-formed due to a substitution failure in the immediate context, the whole `void_if_well_formed<..>` will produce a substitution failure in the immediate context. These kinds of errors can be used by a technique called SFINAE: Substitution Failure Is Not An Error. It might be more appropriately be named Substitution Failure In The Immediate Context Is Not An Error.

SFINAE can be exploited e.g. by declaring two function templates. Let `expression<T>()` stand for any expression that is dependent on `T`.

```
template<typename T, void_if_well_formed<decltype(expression<T>())>* = nullptr>
std::true_type  test(std::nullptr_t);

template<typename T>
std::false_type test(void*);
```

If we now call the test via `test<some_type>(nullptr)`, the first overload is preferred because the argument types matches exactly the function parameter type. However, the second overload is also viable. If the first overload is ill-formed due to SFINAE, it is removed from the overload set and the second overload is chosen instead:

```
template<typename T>
using test_result = decltype( test<T>(nullptr) );
```

Using these techniques, we can implement `level1` as follows:

```
template<typename TLeafType>
class level1
{
public:
    template <Index N, typename T = TLeafType>
    using output_t =
        decltype(std::declval<T*>() ->
                 getOutputImpl(PortIdxType<N>{}, std::declval<crPolyIndex>()));

    static constexpr Natural getOutputPortsNumber(void)
        {return getOutputPortsNumberImpl<0>(nullptr);}

    template<Index N>
    static constexpr Index getOutputPortsNumberImpl(void*)
        {return N;}

    template<Index N, typename T = TLeafType,
             void_if_well_formed<output_t<N, T>>* = nullptr>
    static constexpr Index getOutputPortsNumberImpl(std::nullptr_t)
        {return getOutputPortsNumberImpl<N + 1>(nullptr);}

};
```

With [slightly more work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26533335), we can even write this as follows:

```
template<Index N>
struct HasOutputFor
{
    static auto P() -> PortIdxType<N>;
    static auto cr() -> crPolyIndex;
    
    template<typename T>
    static auto requires_(T&& t) -> decltype(t.getOutputImpl(P(), cr()));
};

template<Index N, typename T = TLeafType, REQUIRE( HasOutputFor<N>(T) )>
static constexpr Index getOutputPortsNumberImpl(std::nullptr_t);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a very detailed answer. Your answer helped greatly both in understanding some of the language concepts and in finding an appropriate solution for my problem.