# Smooth transition of interface change

Tags: c++, c++14

Consider the following situation, where a base class prescribes a function that can be reimplemented in a derived class:

```
template<typename Impl>
class Base {
public:
    void f(double& value, double param)
    { value = 0.0; }
};

class Implementation : public Base<Implementation> {
public:
    void f(double& value, double param)
    { value = param; }
};

int main()
{
    Implementation imp;
    double value = 0.0;
    imp.f(value, 1.0);
}
```

Suppose that I want to change the signature of the function `f` in the base class to `double f(double param)` and to use that for `Base` and derived classes. I want to perform this change without breaking immediately all implementation classes. Instead, a provider of an implementation class should get a deprecation warning. I came up with the following:

```
template<typename Impl>
class Base {
public:
    double f(double param) __attribute__ ((deprecated))
    {
        double v = 0.0;
        static_cast<Impl*>(this)->f(v, param);
        return v;
    }
    void f(double& value, double param)
    { value = 0.0; }
};

// class Implementation as before

int main()
{
    Implementation imp;
    double value = imp.f(1.0);
}
```

As a result, the `Base` version of `f` should only be called if `f` isn't reimplemented in `Implementation` with the new signature, yielding the desired deprecation warning.

Obviously, this doesn't compile because the definition of `f` in `Implementation` shadows the `f` in `Base`:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Implementation::f(double)’
     double value = imp.f(1.0);
```

One solution would be to add `using`:

```
class Implementation : public Base<Implementation> {
public:
    using Base<Implementation>::f;
    void f(double& value, double param)
    { value = param; }
};
```

That would force the provider of `Implementation` to change immediately his code which is exactly what should be avoided in the first place. Another possibility would be to change the name `f` in the new signature. I also would like to avoid this since `f` has a really good name in my real use case.

So my question is: Can I perform the signature change

- such that providers of `Implementation` get a deprecation warning, but their code is not broken immediately, i.e., without changes to `Implementation`, and
- without having to rename `f`?

Comment: Just a question, unrelated to the problem: Why isn't the method, in an interface, marked as `virtual`? What's the use of the interface if the methods can't be overriden? Or, better yet, why does it throw an exception, rather than being marked as pure-virtual (which is the go-to way of writing interfaces in C++).

Comment: What's wrong with the `using` solution?

Comment: This is a simplified version of a real case with more complex class interdependencies. Static binding is preferred over dynamic one by using CRTP. I tried to boil it down as much as possible while keeping the essential character.

Comment: I don't want `using` since the provider of `Implementation` should not be force to change his code immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I could construct a solution that works for me from [jrok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824239/6671978) to the question [Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/87372/6671978):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename, typename T>
struct hasFunctionF {};

template<typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct hasFunctionF<C, Ret(Args...)> {
private:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T*)
    -> typename
        std::is_same<
            decltype( std::declval<T>().f( std::declval<Args>()... ) ),
            Ret    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        >::type;  // attempt to call it and see if the return type is correct

    template<typename>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};

template<typename Impl>
class Base {
public:
    template<class T = Impl>
    __attribute__ ((deprecated))
    const typename std::enable_if_t<hasFunctionF<T, void(double&, double)>::value, double> g(double param)
    {
        double v = 0.0;
        static_cast<Impl*>(this)->f(v, param);
        return v;
    }

    template<class T = Impl>
    const typename std::enable_if_t<hasFunctionF<T, double(double)>::value, double> g(double param)
    {
        return static_cast<Impl*>(this)->f(param);
    }
};

class OldImplementation : public Base<OldImplementation> {
public:
    void f(double& value, double param)
    { value = param; }
};

class NewImplementation : public Base<NewImplementation> {
public:
    double f(double param)
    { return param; }
};

int main()
{
    OldImplementation oldImp;
    double value = oldImp.g(1.0);
    std::cout << "old: " << value << std::endl;
    NewImplementation newImp;
    std::cout << "new: " << newImp.g(1.0) << std::endl;
}
```

I still have to introduce a new function name `g` in the base class and use that name for calling. But I don't think that this can be avoided without changing user code. The user code is `OldImplementation` which has not to be changed immediately. Compiling user code that employs the old interface only gives a deprecation warning. That's exactly what I wanted to achieve.