# Template class to call some function of other classes based on their presence and priority and more type restrictions like const and case sensitivity

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I have structs/classes like these:

```
struct LD {                             //Login detail
        std::string username;
        std::string password;

        std::string toString() const {
        return "Username: " + username
    + " Password: " + password;
    }
};

struct UP {                          //User Profile
    std::string name;
    std::string email;

    ostream& pPrint(ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "Name: " << name
        << " Email: " << email;
        return ost;
    }

std::string toString() const {
    return "NULLSTRING";
    }
};

struct CD {       //ContactDetails
    std::string m_phoneNumber; 
    std::string m_address; 
    ostream& pPrint(ostream& ost) { //NO CONST must not print
        ost << "PhoneNumber: " << m_phoneNumber << " Address:" << m_address;
        return ost; 
    } 
} ; 

struct H { 
    std::string hobbies;
    ostream& PPrint(ostream& ost) {  //its not case equivalent and not const so it should not be called
        ost << "Hobbies: " << m_hobbies; 
        return ost; 
    } 
} ; 

struct PD { 
    std::string cardNumber; 
    ostream& pPrint(ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "CardNumber: " << m_cardNumber;
        return ost; 
    } 
} ; 

struct BN { 
    std::string m_bankName; 
    std::string toString() const {
        return "BANKNAME"; 
        } 

    ostream& simplePrint(ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "BankName: " << m_bankName;
        return ost; 
    }
} ; 

struct DI { 
    std::string toString() const { 
        return "i0S"; 
        } 

    ostream& pPrint(ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "Android: JellyBean";
        return ost; 
    }
};
```

I am creating a template `PPrint` class which will call `pPrint` function of that class if its present. If not, it will call `toString` function of that class if its also not available it will print *NO print function*.

Priorities:

1. Invoke `pPrint`
2. Invoke `toString`
3. Simply output *NO print Function*

My main function:

```
int main() {
    LD ld = { "And", "Ap" };
    UP  up = { "James Brannd", "jamens@goo.com" };
    CD cd = { "+9198799911", "355 B. Bway, NY" };
    H hb = { "sing, dance, read"}; 
    PD pd = { "444411113336667732222" }; 
    BN bn = { "SBI" }; 
    DI di; 

    std::cout << PPrint <UP> (up) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <LD> (ld) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <CD> (cd) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <H>(hb) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <PD> (pd) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << PPrint <BN> (bn) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <DI> (di) << std::endl; 
}
```

Now I have created this class as below:

```
template<class...>
using void_t = void;

// pPrint
template<typename T, typename = void_t<>>
struct HaspPrintMethod : std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct HaspPrintMethod<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>  ().pPrint(std::declval<std::ostream&>()))>> : std::true_type{};

// PPrint
template<typename T, typename = void_t<>>
struct HasPPrintMethod : std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct HasPPrintMethod<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().PPrint(std::declval<std::ostream&>()))>> : std::true_type{};

template<typename T>
using HasPPrintMethod_t = typename HasPPrintMethod<T>::type;

// both pPrint and PPrint
template<typename T>
struct HasAnyPPrintMethod : std::integral_constant<bool,    HasPPrintMethod<T>::value || HaspPrintMethod<T>::value>{};

template<typename T>
using HasAnyPPrintMethod_t = typename HasAnyPPrintMethod<T>::type;

template<typename T, typename=void_t<>>
struct HastoStringMethod : std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct HastoStringMethod<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().toString())>> : std::true_type{};

template<typename T>
using HastoStringMethod_t = typename HastoStringMethod<T>::type;

template <class T>
class PPrint {
    public:
    PrettyPrint(T m)
    {
        CallPrint(m, HasAnyPPrintMethod_t<T>());
    }

    std::string buf;

    private:
    void CallPrint( T& m, std::true_type)
    {
        CallPPrint(m, HasPPrintMethod_t<T>());

    }

    void CallPPrint(T& m, std::true_type)
    {
        std::ostringstream  os;
        m.PPrint(os); //need correction as pPrint is only priority for THis "NO print function" if pPrint is nor there and toString is not there I mean it should ignored
        buf = os.str();
    }

    void CallPrettyPrint(T& m, std::false_type)
    {
        std::ostringstream  os;
        m.pPrint(os);  //only i want this one as 1st priority PPrint must be not used anywhere , should not be printed
        buf = os.str();
    }

    void CallPrint( T& m, std::false_type)
    {
        CallPrintNoPPrint(m, HastoStringMethod_t<T>());
    }

    void CallPrintNoPPrint( T& m, std::true_type)
    {
        buf = m.toString();
    }
    void CallPrintNoPrettyPrint( T& m, std::false_type)
    {
        buf = "NO print Function";
    }

};
```

It's not correct because it's not distinguishing for const and its giving error like below for my compiler but running on others and printing `H`'s function (which it must not print):

```
error: ‘struct UP’ has no member named ‘PPrint’
         m.PrettyPrint(os);
```

But it's running fine on ideone and Coliru.

How should I create such class or remove such errors?
Main challenges are:

1. Prioriy (mentioned earlier)
2. Case sensitive same function
3. Const type distinguish function should be `pPrint` only and const too.
4. You cant what's inside any of the struct and main function that is template class should be seperate and independent.
5. Only C++11 standards

The class should work for this two prototype only:

1. `ostream& pPrint(ostream& ost) const // case sentive for pPrint`
2. `std::string toString() const`

References:

1. [Template class to call some named function of other classes based on their presence and priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488450/template-class-to-call-some-named-function-of-other-classes-based-on-their-prese)
2. [Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to reduce the boilerplate of your solution and solve the issue:

```
struct SimplyOutput {};
struct ToString: SimplyOutput {};
struct PPrint: ToString {};

template<typename T>
void pPrintImpl(SimplyOutput, const T &) {
    // Do whatever you want here
}

template<typename T>
auto pPrintImpl(ToString, const T &t)
-> decltype(t.toString()) {
    // Do whatever you want here
}

template<typename T>
auto pPrintImpl(PPrint, const T &t)
-> decltype(t.pPrint(std::declval<std::ostream>())) {
    // Do whatever you want here
}

template<typename T>
auto pPrint(const T &t)
-> decltype(pPrintImpl(PPrint{}, t)) {
    return pPrintImpl(PPrint{}, t);
}
```

Overloading, inheritance and sfinae will do the job.

---

Below a minimal, working example based on the code in the question:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

struct LD {                             //Login detail
        std::string username;
        std::string password;

        std::string toString() const {
        return "Username: " + username
    + " Password: " + password;
    }
};

struct UP {                          //User Profile
    std::string name;
    std::string email;

    std::ostream& pPrint(std::ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "Name: " << name
        << " Email: " << email;
        return ost;
    }

std::string toString() const {
    return "NULLSTRING";
    }
};

struct CD {       //ContactDetails
    std::string m_phoneNumber; 
    std::string m_address; 
    std::ostream& pPrint(std::ostream& ost) { //NO CONST must not print
        ost << "PhoneNumber: " << m_phoneNumber << " Address:" << m_address;
        return ost; 
    } 
} ; 


struct H { 
    std::string m_hobbies;
    std::ostream& PPrint(std::ostream& ost) {  //its not case equivalent and not const so it should not be called
        ost << "Hobbies: " << m_hobbies; 
        return ost; 
    } 
} ; 

struct PD { 
    std::string m_cardNumber; 
    std::ostream& pPrint(std::ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "CardNumber: " << m_cardNumber;
        return ost; 
    } 
} ; 

struct BN { 
    std::string m_bankName; 
    std::string toString() const {
        return "BANKNAME"; 
        } 

    std::ostream& simplePrint(std::ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "BankName: " << m_bankName;
        return ost; 
    }
} ; 

struct DI { 
    std::string toString() const { 
        return "i0S"; 
        } 

    std::ostream& pPrint(std::ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "Android: JellyBean";
        return ost; 
    }
};

template<typename T>
class PPrint {
    struct SimplyOutputTag {};
    struct ToStringTag: SimplyOutputTag {};
    struct PPrintTag: ToStringTag {};

    template<typename U = T>
    void internal(SimplyOutputTag, const U &) {
        buf = "NO print Function";
    }

    template<typename U = T>
    auto internal(ToStringTag, const U &u)
    -> decltype(u.toString(), void()) {
        buf = u.toString();
    }

    template<typename U = T>
    auto internal(PPrintTag, const U &u)
    -> decltype(u.pPrint(std::declval<std::ostringstream &>()), void()) {
        std::ostringstream os;
        u.pPrint(os);
        buf = os.str();
    }

public:
    PPrint(const T &t) {
        internal(PPrintTag{}, t);
    }

    std::string get() const { return buf; }

private:
    std::string buf;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, const PPrint<T> &pp) {
    os << pp.get();
    return os;
}

int main() {
    LD ld = { "And", "Ap" };
    UP  up = { "James Brannd", "jamens@goo.com" };
    CD cd = { "+9198799911", "355 B. Bway, NY" };
    H hb = { "sing, dance, read"}; 
    PD pd = { "444411113336667732222" }; 
    BN bn = { "SBI" }; 
    DI di; 

    std::cout << PPrint <UP> (up) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <LD> (ld) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <CD> (cd) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <H>(hb) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <PD> (pd) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << PPrint <BN> (bn) << std::endl;
    std::cout << PPrint <DI> (di) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: any demo? Skypjack

Comment: @VenuKantSahu Simply use this instead of your stuff. It should work _as is_, more or less.

Comment: I am  not familiar with this type of style, so i will require a demo or any good place to learn this? @skypjack

Comment: PPrint should be a template class first of all to this as I can't change whats inside main or what's inside struct.

Comment: @VenuKantSahu Added a minimal, working example based on your code. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a77e2b14a4b4b27d) or the answer above.