# Dispatch for binary and unary callables in C++03

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits, c++03

I'm having troubles implementing this in legacy C++, but I'm pretty sure it can be done. Say I have a higher order function that needs two versions, one for unary callables (function objects, functions, member functions)

```
template <class F>
void ho_fun(F argFun) { 
    int arg1; 
    argFun(arg1); 
}
```

and one for binary:

```
template <class F>
void ho_fun(F argFun) { 
    int arg1, arg2; 
    argFun(arg1, arg2); 
}
```

I'm looking for a complete solution in terms of "callable type" (otherwise I'd obviously use [arity](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html) from function traits for this) i.e. support for functions **and** function objects.

I'm translating [this](https://functionalcpp.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/function-traits/) lovely post to C++03 (remove `...` and `using` typedefs) but it doesn't seem to work.

PS. I'm not solving the particular problem listed above, that's just the [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Also I mention C++03 because I'm working on legacy code for this project and a modern solution is of no use to me. By all means feel free to post a modern one but please consider helping me as well.

Comment: I don't get it.  The code in the question does not work but you don't want to know what is wrong with it anyway?

Comment: The right way to do this is varadics. Why are you trying to get rid of the `...`s?

Comment: @NathanOliver Usually my examples are mistaken for the actual problem I want to solve. The actual problem is "dispatch for unary and binary code", I'm mentioning the PS to avoid answers like "pass another argument" or "create an extra overload"

Comment: @LorahAttkins Aha.  Just got it.  Can you use boost?  I think they have something built for this in C++03.

Comment: @JonathanMee Because the environment I'm working on (about 3M lines of legacy C++ code) uses a C++03 compiler and variadics were only introduced in C++11

Comment: How about boost::function<T>::arity? This is C++03...

Comment: I'm mentioning `arity` in the question. Arity does not support function objects, last I check it only works for free functions and this I have implemented already (it's simple pattern matching with template specializations)

Comment: @LorahAttkins From the example you've shown you're just passing some unknown arguments into a function pointer passed to the code. That's obviously not useful code. can you provide more information on what you want `ho_fun` to accomplish? There are other ways around this, but without more information from you choosing one would be impossible.

Comment: @JonathanMee You can look at it as a thought experiment. The abstract is preety clear: "Can you create a metaprogram to discover the arity of a callable?". Me asking for dispatching based on unary or binary callables, is already a workaround.

Comment: @LorahAttkins So you're not looking to call the function? You simply want to take in a function pointer and return whether it requires 1 or 2 arguments? You're not trying to actually have `ho_fun` call anything?

Comment: @JonathanMee I want ho_fun to vary its behavior based on the arity of the callable we'll pass to it. Of course I'll be calling the function argument, but unless I correctly dispatch there's a compilation error.

Comment: I'd go to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10707822/2412846) and check whether the function is unary or binary. On base of this, I'd SFINAE-out the inappropriate version.

Comment: I seem to recall having tackled a similar problem some time ago while running tests for `cxxomfort`'s tuple and function traits, but I'd have to search through to find the code. The most important limitation I remember is that in order to work it needed something like `__typeof` to be available; at that point, it's just a matter of explicitly specializing the required arities (because C++03 lacks variadics) and constnesses (for member functions, etc) for the "function object" case.

Comment: There is no way in to ask C++03 questions like "are objects of this type callable with these arguments?" You can only ask "is this a function type with this exact signature" or "is this a class type that has operator() with this exact signature?"

Answer (score 1):

This answer provides a solution to the question I understand you to be asking:

## How can I specialize a function so that it can detect whether it's argument is a unary or binary function, method, or functor?

In [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) your only option is to write specializations for each of these, and incidentally you'll need to make specializations for `const` methods as well as non-`const` methods:

```
template <typename Arg, typename Result>
void ho_fun(Result(*argFun)(Arg)) {
    Arg arg = 13;

    argFun(arg);
}

template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Result>
void ho_fun(Result (*argFun)(Arg1, Arg2)) {
    Arg1 arg1 = 13;
    Arg2 arg2 = 42;

    argFun(arg1, arg2);
}

template <typename T, typename Arg, typename Result>
void ho_fun(Result(T::*argFun)(Arg)) {
    T myClass;
    Arg arg = 13;

    (myClass.*argFun)(arg);
}

template <typename T, typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Result>
void ho_fun(Result(T::*argFun)(Arg1, Arg2)) {
    T myClass;
    Arg1 arg1 = 13;
    Arg2 arg2 = 42;

    (myClass.*argFun)(arg1, arg2);
}

template <typename T, typename Arg, typename Result>
void ho_fun(Result(T::*argFun)(Arg) const) {
    T myClass;
    Arg arg = 13;

    (myClass.*argFun)(arg);
}

template <typename T, typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Result>
void ho_fun(Result(T::*argFun)(Arg1, Arg2) const) {
    T myClass;
    Arg1 arg1 = 13;
    Arg2 arg2 = 42;

    (myClass.*argFun)(arg1, arg2);
}

template <class T>
void ho_fun(T argFun) {
    ho_fun(&T::operator());
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/TDrkYQ)