# Sometimes call function from within a variadic template function

Tags: c++, serialization

I have a basic message class that I am using to serialize data and then send that data through a socket:

```
std::vector<char> m_rawMessageData;
int m_currentReadPosition = 0;

template<typename writeDataType>
void LoadData(writeDataType &inData)
{
    int dataSize = sizeof(writeDataType);
    int currentSize = m_rawMessageData.size();

    m_rawMessageData.resize(dataSize + m_rawMessageData.size());
    std::memcpy(&m_rawMessageData.at(currentSize), &(inData), dataSize);
}

template<typename ReadDataType>
int GetData(ReadDataType &outData)
{
    std::stringstream dataReader;

    int dataSize = sizeof(ReadDataType);

    if (m_currentReadPosition + dataSize > m_rawMessageData.size())
        return 0;

    std::memcpy(&outData, &m_rawMessageData.at(m_currentReadPosition),
        dataSize);  

    m_currentReadPosition += dataSize;

    return dataSize;
}
```

I know there are some possible bugs/errors in this code if these are called incorrectly, but I'm the only developer right now, and I need to get something working.  Also, I'm assuming that only basic types will be passed, and that endiness is the same on both ends.

I want this message class to be able to handle structs.  My thought was this: in each of my structs I will write a "Serialize/Deserialize" function. Then, in my LoadData and GetData calls, I will check if there is a "Serialize/Deserialize" function and then call it instead of doing the generic memcpy.

I was able to check if there is a serialize function using something similar to the code in this question:
[Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)

But I'm not sure how I am suppose to call the "Serialize" function.  I can't simply use "inData.Serialize()", as that fails to compile.

So in short, I want my LoadData Function to look something like this:

```
template<typename writeDataType>
void LoadData(writeDataType &inData)
{
    //Check if writeDataType has Serialize Function. 
    if (serializeDoesExist)
    {
         inData.Serialize(m_rawMessageData);
    }
    else
    {
        int dataSize = sizeof(writeDataType);
        int currentSize = m_rawMessageData.size();

        m_rawMessageData.resize(dataSize + m_rawMessageData.size());
        std::memcpy(&m_rawMessageData.at(currentSize), &(inData), dataSize);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE:  My boss does not like to add external libraries to project unless absolutely necessary.  That's why I haven't gone with Protobuf or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`std::experimental::isdetected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), you can create the traits:

```
template<class T>
using serialize_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().Serialize());

template <typename T>
using has_serialize = std::experimental::is_detected<serialize_t, T>;
```

and then, using SFINAE:

```
template<typename writeDataType>
std::enable_if_t<has_serialize<writeDataType>::value>
LoadData(writeDataType &inData)
{
    inData.Serialize(m_rawMessageData);
}

template<typename writeDataType>
std::enable_if_t<!has_serialize<writeDataType>::value>
LoadData(writeDataType &inData)
{
    int dataSize = sizeof(writeDataType);
    int currentSize = m_rawMessageData.size();

    m_rawMessageData.resize(dataSize + m_rawMessageData.size());
    std::memcpy(&m_rawMessageData.at(currentSize), &(inData), dataSize);
}
```

Comment: Very nice, it even simplifies the detection step.  Any chance this could be done with only C++14?  If not, I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer, since it's both elegant and straightforward.

Comment: `std::experimental::detected` can be implemented with C++11. (link give possible implementation, dependencies as `std::void_t` can also be done in C++11).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-catch statement to check if this function exists.

```
try{
    inData.Serialize();
}catch(<You can specify the exception here, or just write "..." to catch any exception>...){
    <What you want to do if the function does not exists>
}
```

If you want more detailed information about try-catch and exception handling:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_exceptions_handling.htm

Comment: I don't believe this will work, since "inData" is a typename.  The problem is I can't write inData.Serialize() in the first place, as that causes a compiler error.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I saw "inData" as an instance.
Then you probably have to use SFINAE. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you write a LoadData/GetData pair that are specialized using std::enable_if, checking for the presence of the needed member. The specialized forms use those members while the generic forms continue to use memcpy

Comment: Do you mean write a specialized LoadData/GetData for every struct I have defined in my program?  A possible solution I suppose, but I would really like to keep it generic.

Comment: No, I meant use std::enable_if and your member detection to choose a specialization that would use the member if it is present but have the not-present pair continue to use memcpy. It might turn out that both the present and not-present forms of LoadData and GetData would need an std::enable_if parameter (one where the condition is true the other where it is not). That way each LoadData/GetData has only the code appropriate to that code path.