# Why does conditionally compiling an operator template change the availability of another operator?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, eigen, enable-if

This is kind of a followup question to my previous one ([Unified way for checking the existence of member functions, free functions and operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862751/unified-way-for-checking-the-existence-of-member-functions-free-functions-and-o)).

I am trying to generate operators for `scalar * vector` and `vector * scalar` only if they are not provided by the vector class at hand.
I check if those operators exist in the following way:

```
template<typename C, typename Ret, typename Arg>
struct has_operator_mult {
private:
    template<typename L, typename R, std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_convertible
        <
            decltype(std::declval<L>() * std::declval<R>()),
            Ret
        >::value
    > * = nullptr >
        static constexpr std::true_type check(nullptr_t);

    template<typename, typename>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

public:
    typedef decltype(check<C, Arg>(nullptr)) type;
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};
```

For vectors from the Eigen library (version 3.3.4) this produces:

```
has_operator_mult<Vector3f, Vector3f, float>::value; // true -> Vector3f = Vector3f * float
has_operator_mult<float, Vector3f, Vector3f>::value; // true -> Vector3f = float * Vector3f

has_operator_mult<Vector3f, Vector3f, std::vector<float>>::value // false
```

which is fine. However, as soon as I try to declare the righthandside multiplication operator:

```
template<typename TVector3D,
    std::enable_if_t
    <
        !has_operator_mult<TVector3D, TVector3D, float>::value
    > * = nullptr
>
TVector3D operator*(const TVector3D & lhs, float rhs)
{
    return TVector3D{}; // implementation does not matter here
}
```

the output changes to

```
has_operator_mult<Vector3f, Vector3f, float>::value; // true  -> Vector3f = Vector3f * float
has_operator_mult<float, Vector3f, Vector3f>::value; // false -> Vector3f = float * Vector3f
```

So the operator that I am not declaring myself somhow vanishes according to my existence check. 
Interestingly this does not change whether I use

```
std::enable_if_t
<
    !has_operator_mult<TVector3D, TVector3D, float>::value // with negation
>
```

or

```
std::enable_if_t
<
    has_operator_mult<TVector3D, TVector3D, float>::value // without negation
>
```

Both operators however are still callable, but call the implementations of the Eigen library.

```
Vector3f v(1, 2, 3);
std::cout << v * 5.f << std::endl << std::endl;
std::cout << 5.f * v << std::endl << std::endl;
```

When I add the other multiplication operator, things get even more confusing:

```
template<typename TVector3D,
    std::enable_if_t
    <
        !has_operator_mult<float, TVector3D, TVector3D>::value
    > * = nullptr
>
TVector3D operator*(float lhs, const TVector3D & rhs)
{
    return TVector3D{};
}

has_operator_mult<Vector3f, Vector3f, float>::value; // false -> Vector3f = Vector3f * float
has_operator_mult<float, Vector3f, Vector3f>::value; // true  -> Vector3f = float * Vector3f

Vector3f v(1, 2, 3);
std::cout << v * 5.f << std::endl << std::endl; // calls my implementation
std::cout << 5.f * v << std::endl << std::endl; // calls Eigen implementation

std::cout << v * 5 << std::endl << std::endl; // compiler error, ambiguous function call
std::cout << 5 * v << std::endl << std::endl; // calls Eigen implementation
```

Why is this happening? Is the check for the existence of the operator wrong? It seems to work as long as I am not declaring operators myself.

Comment: I think you are in UB land (or near), as `has_operator_mult<float, TVector3D, TVector3D>::value` would have different value, before and after your overload.

Comment: That would be the case if TVector3D is a type that does not provide such an operator. In such a situation I would want `has_operator_mult` inside of `enable_if` to be evaluated to false so that the template is instanciated for this type. 
In the code above Eigen::Vector3f already has the desired operator which somehow seems to not be recognized by MSVC -- at least when put inside the template parameter. GCC seems to handle this just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gcc and clang your code snippets work fine, but not with MSVC. So I recommend you to report the issue to the MSVC team.

You can try by yourself with the three compilers [there](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwtjzBMLAPSaSmDdg4AGAIJyFSlZnVaAbpmRFiZyzesFMAWwAHZj8NTQIAT0D9Jn9HTVJVSOiWWMcAJUwCROSYuNUrYmAva0ECYhF3VQQmQQB9VGjiJg86/xEGAnUAdj5rQOI8ZxbJb1VxpIDgkbDc1PyAGRyovIzEsvQQEBiAIwZMOrwAMzqCMLGJy42tvHq0FldiAjw902tLy/P3j5%2BsJVyINcQH8GMMGGEFmYIABKVQAKlUQJBYLC6Sh0OhpAuP0umTO3x%2BZi2YJEbysn1k2HhTgAIqoWB0GIFyk5zASPmUWnhkKp7mVMAAPAaIgibEDlUmnFa8hBuADWgNFWwZDCZ5VO0I0fR85ImfiCIVMWjmaWWKTSJV1405zx5fL8QuIIrFRyYDEEB1yMvlEAAdP7NbJtd5AiI9tyQNikissEdVCCAchZcg5WEEgUilCVWriBjo9EtVGbdzeagWPzHaodqhUAxVCTHBo6bliW7SYXrBxujSOzqyhUqsgRGVUP4enxu73vPrpqFjSt5o4ACoANTcHlkNKx7KBu32hxO%2BKtTk0UcuYDANXqjUwzVa7U6YVX65Im8Sz/cr63qiODFQLSJEAGyjMxqSbelGWZTxO0pbwhxHMcbzvEg4Qge1VA/Dc6W4AA2VQGAQQREl/f8umIQjNU7Xoo2ILIxBYXlhyIfwuwnHsg1UAwDFUPADQCfQCC5Mt41QTBBHpVAun8Fo/CdWVaO8Lse07XwpkNWYFzSDC10/Yg3yLJVtlSV4D1OECtDPCYLyvBomhaEg2g6M4tBIlp3x0rD3JfPT2OwVtlDJCkqQRcDsygxTYOseDmNUJD7OIVDXK6AiiNLcsukwr91C4PDyMESibGo9laIIejGIQ1ilKnScVKsftKikiJXB5SrJyDRTrAUKSmAUGFxwMrlkDqWoPSeCBqlqWzb3ixzHy0HQ9BYLYPNfI5EgW/Rlu82Q1p/P8AMpfzSSxLguG4LhA21K5BNtYbBFGghxpsuL7ycsIkvW3RNpAFa9N2jalp%2B7ajkAhsTrO07LoG26RtvR7rMml6HIfZztC%2BwHfp2z7Fq23SsedYlvPe/bnPMQ6gLbTBwfOqH2QB3GNzjZwIHoVQuESWRaePemgbxuNiFoWl62pABWX0Qfaun0YZ1bVGILghbFuMEWcXtLh5zH%2BdkIXnFFtWJg14G5YAFkV6lVcl49/CatxVCYfXxi46LRzlkWhaYUXxYdziDGdsdiDw8Clepe3LcuEqyosarlJ1KRMQYaQRakUglqkCxk9QaRT14fhEVEcRGy4WRaGTghpHTjFSDlEBZAATl9Y2cJw2uAA4LC4Cxum6Dva5wxhpGN5PU/T0hM6kZPBBACxSDLtO49IOBYCQNAgjwfYyAoNDR0CNfbxQZg2Bwixp6ONfZMniAdnL5OdgUJhiAiaQS9IFe4hYAgAHkWAYR%2B59ILBpJsH2Nff%2BeBaLuCGGJEBgo3AiD8E/ZOXVMAJz/uUXi1946sHYPwfgjAXiT1gIubY6NSCPGkLIWQg9K6NGeGWSeUgAC0H9tYMI2E2TgOdeC0EHkIfOEg6Dx0TkPEBY8BQtxwgwnCpslBYNUDhX0FgFGqAgLgQgJBsrF0SMYVe68NG0FhNnPgvBS4YMxNXLg3RfS0Frr3cRxsRYt1rvY7u3R%2B5SB4cPDO0gJ5TxnhgheMBEAgFEAQUM2RN4rx3uvOgpBMD4A8DEgA7s0QICDBFSCTinER0g5CC0SYQBAqgxESKkbyA%2BwA5EKIUSYueldq4UN9BQppzSWluI8dk8eQhfGzwrukrgwi/5jxqb00ht5BB4DLCAY2QA%3D%3D).

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned the compiler I am working on. I filed a report here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/235349/conditionally-compiling-template-operator-overload.html

Comment: Work around: using `typename std::enable_if<cond>::type` instead of `std::enable_if_t<cond>` fixes SFINAE on MSVC  (at least in some cases).