# Why is the pointer in the argument required during SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++03, c++98

Why do I need a `*` to make `checker` as pointer on line

`template <typename C> static yes test( checker<C, &C::helloworld>* );`

for the compile time deductions to work correctly, outputting `1 0`?

When I remove the `*`, the output is `0 0`

```
#include <iostream>

struct Generic {}; 
struct Hello
{ int helloworld() { return 0; } };

// SFINAE test
template <typename T>
class has_helloworld
{
    typedef char                yes;
    typedef struct {char _[2];}  no; 

    template <typename C, int (C::*)()> struct checker;

    template <typename C> static yes test( checker<C, &C::helloworld>* );
    template <typename C> static no  test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes) };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << has_helloworld<Hello>::value   << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_helloworld<Generic>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This was an exercise from me trying to put together these two posts:

[Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

[Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's called as `test<T>(0)`, and `0` could be accepted as a null pointer if `test` takes a pointer as parameter type (as `checker<C, &C::helloworld>*`).

If you remove `*` to make the parameter type to `checker<C, &C::helloworld>`, `test<T>(0)` could only match `test(...)` then you'll always get the result `0`.

Comment: upvote for explaining the mystery, without losing the mysticism to it that is C++.