# C++: `enable_if` to restrict types that support specific arithmetic operations

Tags: c++, sfinae

I would like to define template function that can be applied only to types that support multiplication, e.g. `int`, `long`, `float`, and custom types with overloaded operators like `Martix`:

```
class Matrix {
    public:
        Matrix operator*(const Matrix& other) const;
}
```

Is it possible to restrict template type in this way?

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< /* multiplication is defined */ >>
T power (T base, unsigned int exponent) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)

Comment: That won't work for int, float, and double

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to test, if a type can be multiplied by itself, you can use:

```
template <class T, 
          class = decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<T>())>
T power (T base, unsigned int exponent) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) from *fundamentals TS v2* (there is also a possible implementation provided). This provides you with a good base in case you want to do frequent checks on various operations. It basically allows you to check if a specified operation is possible on the given types.

First, you define your operation type:

```
template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
using multiplication_t = decltype(std::declval<Lhs>() * std::declval<Rhs>());
```

then you make a type trait out of it:

```
template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
constexpr bool can_multiply = is_detected<multiplication_t, Lhs, Rhs>::value;
```

You can now use the trait as a condition for `enabled_if`:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<can_multiply<T, unsigned int>>
T power (T base, unsigned int exponent) {
    // ...
}
```

This also adds some readability (imo at least), cause `can_multiply` clearly expresses your intention.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/tUodud) is a full implementation as example.

[Another](https://godbolt.org/z/5yhz_r) example with more operations.