# C++ force derived classes to implement static function

Tags: c++, static, compile-time

I am trying to create Comparator class for objects of some class A. To achieve this I want to create base class `BaseComparator` and derive `AComparator` and `BComparator` from it. Is there a way to force all classes derived from `BaseComparator` to implement function `bool compare(const A &a, const A &b)` so

```cpp
class AComparator : public BaseComparator {
    static bool compare(const A &a, const A &b) { return true; }
}
```

will compile and

```cpp
class BComparator : public BaseComparator {
}
```

will throw a compile-time error?

There is a way to achieve this with abstract class, which doesn't satisfy me as it requires a class to have a pure virtual function (while my classes don't have a state but only static functions and I do not need their instances).

Comment: If you want polymorphism, then you will need an instance and you will need `virtual`. If you don't, inheritance doesn't have much to offer here. The standard library actually does the complete opposite of what you are trying here, it's function objects don't inherit from anything but are instantiated. Anyway, C++20 introduces [Concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that here are no `static` member functions in the code you've shown. Did you forget to include the `static` keyword?

Comment: If you implement `BaseComparator` with the [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp) you could check if the derived type [has the required overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature) with a `static_assert`. Edit : Depending on why you use inheritance already, it may be more or less practical.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, the goal here is not to use an inheritance but to make some kind of "interface" which all comparators should satisfy

Comment: Then Concepts is what you are looking for. It's implemented in C++20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), and check passed derived class that:

1. It is really derived class. You can `static_assert` on `std::is_base_of`
2. It has this member function as static function. You can try to access qualified name and static_cast it to function pointer type.

Comment: Thiis should work fine. But remember that if anyone forgets to inherit from the base type, their comparator will probably still work fine. Since no part of the base class is ever necessary, forgetting to inherit will probably not generate any kind of compile time diagnostic. It might be better to just perform the check for the presence of the member wherever the comparator is used instead.