# Why sizeof can accept a function which has no defination?

Tags: c++

I read a code snippet just now:

```
    template<class T>
    struct HasHelloWorld
    {
        typedef char(&yes)[1];
        typedef char(&no)[2];

        template <typename C> static yes check(decltype(&C::HelloWorld));
        template <typename> static no check(...);

        static constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
    };
```

Is this because when `sizeof` accepts an evaluation, the evaluation doesn't get calculated?

Comment: _"...When applied to an expression, sizeof __does not__ evaluate the expression, ..."_   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: consider what you need to know to determine the sizeof the value returned from the call `check<T>(0)`, then consider if you need to know the definition of the function. No, all you need to know is the return type after overload resolution, but actually calling the function is not necessary

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that makes sense.

Comment: though such handwaving and relying on common sense doesnt always work with C++, unfortunately ;)

Comment: note that the code you posted is rather old-fashioned. C++11 introduced a couple of helpers to make such stuff simpler and C++20 introduced a whole new concept of concepts to achieve the same with less arcance code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number could u give me a hint about the modern C++ ways to do this?

Comment: here you can find a lot of different ways, pre-C++11, C++11 and if you scroll down enough also C++20 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature (though it is for a method of fixed signature)